# How to mix coloring and hatching in the same cell in a tabular environment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, color, cell

I have read about hatching [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236024/hatching-table-cells-fails-when-using-positioning) and I understand how to color a cell. But I have a hard time getting a cell both colored and hatched at the same time.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{gry}{gray}{0.90}
\definecolor{grn}{RGB}{169,208,142}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,shadings,patterns,tikzmark}
\newcommand\HatchedCell[4][0pt]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]%
    \fill[#4] ( $ (pic cs:#2) + (0,1.9ex) $ ) rectangle ( $ (pic cs:#3) + (0pt,-#1*\baselineskip-.8ex) $ );
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\begin{document}

\arrayrulecolor{white}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1.5pt}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.075\textwidth}}

\begin{tabular}{P|P|P}
\HatchedCell{start1}{end1}{pattern color=black!70,pattern=north east lines}
\cellcolor{grn}shelf\newline\#1 & 
\cellcolor{grn}shelf\newline\#2 & 
\cellcolor{gry}shelf\newline\#3 \\
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{P|P|P}
\HatchedCell{start1}{end1}{pattern color=black!70,pattern=north east lines}
\cellcolor{grn}shelf\newline\#1 & 
\multicolumn{1}{!{\hspace*{-0.4pt}\vrule\tikzmark{start1}}c!{\vrule\tikzmark{end1}}}%
   {shelf\newline\#2} & 
\cellcolor{gry}shelf\newline\#3 \\
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{P|P|P}
\HatchedCell{start2}{end2}{pattern color=black!70,pattern=north east lines}
\cellcolor{grn}shelf\newline\#1 & 
\multicolumn{1}{!{\hspace*{-0.4pt}\vrule\tikzmark{start2}}c!{\vrule\tikzmark{end2}}}%
   {\cellcolor{grn}shelf\newline\#2} & 
\cellcolor{gry}shelf\newline\#3 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The MWE results in this:

[image]

The first row shows pretty much what I want, except that I need the second entry "shelf #2" hatched. The second and third row show multiple issues. The second row doesn't show the hatching across the entire cell, has a vertical black bar and ignores the `\newline` entry. It's also missing the white vertical ruler to the right of the center cell. The third row shows that cell color appears to take precedence over the hatching.

How do I get this accomplished?

---

After marmot's great help, I've updated the code to make the table content easier to read by closely following the [description](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67092/set-table-background-hatched-and-shaded-using-tikz) further down the first answer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{gry}{gray}{0.90}
\definecolor{grn}{RGB}{169,208,142}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,shadings,patterns,tikzmark}
\newcommand\HatchedCell[5][0pt]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]%
    \path ($(pic cs:#2)!0.5!(pic cs:#3)$) coordinate (aux1) 
    (pic cs:#4) coordinate (aux2);
    \fill[#5] ( $ (aux1) + (-0.67*0.075\textwidth,1.9ex) $ ) 
    rectangle ($ (aux1 |- aux2)  + (0.75*0.075\textwidth,-#1*\baselineskip-.8ex) $ );
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\begin{document}

\arrayrulecolor{white}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1.5pt}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.075\textwidth}}

\newcounter{hatchNumber}\setcounter{hatchNumber}{1}
\newcommand\myHatch[1]{
  \tikzmark{start\arabic{hatchNumber}}\cellcolor{grn}shelf%
  \tikzmark{middle\arabic{hatchNumber}}\newline\##1%
  \tikzmark{end\arabic{hatchNumber}}
  \HatchedCell{start\arabic{hatchNumber}}{middle\arabic{hatchNumber}}%
  {end\arabic{hatchNumber}}{pattern color=black!70,pattern=north east lines}
  \addtocounter{hatchNumber}{1}
}

\begin{tabular}{P|P|P}
\cellcolor{grn}shelf\newline\#1 & 
\myHatch{2} & 
\cellcolor{gry}shelf\newline\#3 \\
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{P|P|P}
\cellcolor{grn}shelf\newline\#4 & 
\myHatch{5} & 
\cellcolor{gry}shelf\newline\#6 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your observations have simple explanations and fixes.

1. The linked answer clearly says that one is to call `\HatchedCell` *outside* the `tabular`, so I did that.
2. You change the cell type to column type `c`, which is why `\newline` has no effect. It is actually not necessary to inorporate `\tikzmark` into a redefinition of the cell type. Since you play with hardcoded distances anyway, one can equally well put it into the cell. To make this work, though, you need to set three `tikzmark`s: one at the beginning of the cell, one at the end of the first line and one at the end of the cell.

Here's the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{gry}{gray}{0.90}
\definecolor{grn}{RGB}{169,208,142}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,shadings,patterns,tikzmark}
\newcommand\HatchedCell[5][0pt]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]%
    \path ($(pic cs:#2)!0.5!(pic cs:#3)$) coordinate (aux1) 
    (pic cs:#4) coordinate (aux2);
    \fill[#5] ( $ (aux1) + (-0.67*0.075\textwidth,1.9ex) $ ) 
    rectangle ($ (aux1 |- aux2)  + (0.75*0.075\textwidth,-#1*\baselineskip-.8ex) $ );
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\begin{document}

\arrayrulecolor{white}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1.5pt}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.075\textwidth}}

\begin{tabular}{P|P|P}
\cellcolor{grn}shelf\newline\#1 & 
\cellcolor{grn}shelf\newline\#2 & 
\cellcolor{gry}shelf\newline\#3 \\
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{P|P|P}
\cellcolor{grn}shelf\newline\#1 & 
\tikzmark{start1}shelf\tikzmark{middle1}\newline\#2\tikzmark{end1} & 
\cellcolor{gry}shelf\newline\#3 \\
\end{tabular}
\HatchedCell{start1}{middle1}{end1}{pattern color=black!70,pattern=north east lines}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{P|P|P}
\cellcolor{grn}shelf\newline\#1 & 
\tikzmark{start2}\cellcolor{grn}shelf\tikzmark{middle2}\newline\#2\tikzmark{end2} & 
\cellcolor{gry}shelf\newline\#3 \\
\end{tabular}
\HatchedCell{start2}{middle2}{end2}{pattern color=black!70,pattern=north east lines}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd like to remark that if you were to draw this with the `matrix` library of Ti*k*Z, this would be way easier.

Comment: Hi marmot, thank you very much for changing the code. This is really helpful. While the fixes may seem simple, I certainly couldn't have come up with the updated definition of the command `\HatchedCell`. What you've provided works like a charm. I need to study tikz more. Again, thanks for the time you've spent on this. I'm sure this is useful for other LaTeX users out there.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. In the following example, we use the key `transparent` of the command `\Block` in order to have the rules drawn in the block (by default with `nicematrix`, the rules are not drawn in the blocks).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\definecolor{gry}{gray}{0.90}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}[hvlines]
\CodeBefore
  \columncolor[RGB]{169,208,142}{2}
\Body
  one & two & three \\
  \Block[transparent, tikz={pattern = north west lines, pattern color = gry}]{1-3}{}
  four & five & six \\
  seven & eight & nine
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]