# Creating hatched cells in a resized table\tabular

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, positioning, resize, tikz-positioning

I'm writing an elsevier `els-cas` article and am trying to hatch some table cells for a table\tabular setting. It seemed to work fine until I used `\resizebox` and set the table size to `\textwidth`. The Tikz hatched cells don't seem to scale correctly. I looked at previous solutions such as [hatching table cells fails when using positioning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236024/hatching-table-cells-fails-when-using-positioning) and [Correctly scaling a tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4338/correctly-scaling-a-tikzpicture) but the solutions don't seem to suit the table environment I'm working with.

For the MWE I wasn't able to fit any hatch correctly in one cell, not to mention two. I'm looking for something like this (see attached picture).

The `MWE`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{cas-dc}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}   

\begin{table}[]
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%




\begin{tabular}{c|ll|llc|cccc|}
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{}}                                  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Unit}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Time}                           & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Non-uniformity}                                                              \\ \cline{4-10} 
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}                      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{2} & 3 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3} & 4                     \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Single-\\ part\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{x}                     & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{}                               & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{}                                                    &                       \\ \cline{2-10} 
                                                                        & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{y}                     & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{}                               & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{}                                                    &                       \\ \cline{2-10} 
                                                                        & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{z}                     & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{}                               & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{}                                                    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Which looks like this:
[image: MWE]
But I hope to create this:
[image: Goal]

Comment: Welcome on TeX StackExchange!

Comment: The [colortbl package](https://ctan.org/pkg/colortbl) may be useful here. That is a plain color (not hatched) but if you choose a light shade of grey or blue it would be a similar effect.

Comment: Many will say to you that it's usually not a good idea to rescale a tabular with `\resizebox` because you will have inconsistent rule widths.

Comment: never do `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%` there is no possibility of getting reasonable output if you scale each table by a different arbitrary value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually want to resize a tabular with `\resizebox` a tabular with hatched cells, you may try `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text

\begin{document}

\sffamily

\lipsum[1]

\tikzset{mypattern/.style = {pattern=grid,pattern color=lightgray}}

\noindent
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccccccc|}[hvlines-except-borders]
\Block{2-1}{} & \Block{2-1}{Unit} & \Block{1-3}{Time} & & & \Block{1-4}{Non-uniformity} &&&\\
& & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\Block{3-1}{Single-\\part} & x & \Block{1-3}{} & & & \Block{1-3}{} \\
                           & y & \Block{1-3}{} & & & \Block{1-3}{} & & & \Block[tikz=mypattern]{}{} \\
                           & z & \Block[tikz=mypattern]{1-3}{} 
                                               & & & \Block[tikz=mypattern]{1-3}{} \\
\Hline
\end{NiceTabular}}
```

You need several compilations because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes.

[image: Output of the first code]

But it's probably better to use `X` columns (in the style of the `X` columns of `{tabularx}`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text

\begin{document}

\sffamily

\lipsum[1]

\tikzset{mypattern/.style = {pattern=grid,pattern color=lightgray}}

\noindent
\begin{NiceTabular}{cc*{7}{X[c]}|}[hvlines-except-borders]
\Block{2-1}{} & \Block{2-1}{Unit} & \Block{1-3}{Time} & & & \Block{1-4}{Non-uniformity} &&&\\
& & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\Block{3-1}{Single-\\part} & x & \Block{1-3}{} & & & \Block{1-3}{} \\
                           & y & \Block{1-3}{} & & & \Block{1-3}{} & & & \Block[tikz=mypattern]{}{} \\
                           & z & \Block[tikz=mypattern]{1-3}{} 
                                               & & & \Block[tikz=mypattern]{1-3}{} \\
\Hline
\end{NiceTabular}


\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]

Comment: Amazing worked like a charm! Thanks a lot!