# How to hatch multicolumn cells instead of colour

Tags: tables, cellcolor

In the following table I want the `\multicolumn` cells hatched in the same way, but I cannot get it to work. For all the cells I now have grey, I would want them hatched with diagonal lines.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow,float}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\cline{2-8}
                                               &                              &                            & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Control measures}                                                                                                                       &                          \\ \cline{4-7}
                                               & \multirow{-2}{*}{Identified} & \multirow{-2}{*}{Occurred} & Overview                                                          & Reason                & Executed                                   & Effect             & \multirow{-2}{*}{Lesson} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                         &                              &                            & ...                                                               & ...                   & *                                          & ...                & ...                      \\ \cline{4-8} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{Risk A}} & \multirow{-2}{*}{*}          & \multirow{-2}{*}{*}        & ...                                                               & ...                   &                                            & ...                & ...                      \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                         &                              &                            & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}                                          &                       & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}                   &                    &                          \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{Risk B}} & \multirow{-2}{*}{*}          & \multirow{-2}{*}{}         & \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}}                        & \multirow{-2}{*}{...} & \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}} & \multirow{-2}{*}{} & \multirow{-2}{*}{...}    \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                         &                              &                            & ...                                                               & ...                   & *                                          & ...                & ...                      \\ \cline{4-8} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{Risk C}} & \multirow{-2}{*}{*}          & \multirow{-2}{*}{}         & ...                                                               & ...                   &                                            & ...                & ...                      \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                         &                              &                            & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}{\color[HTML]{9B9B9B} }                   &                       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}}                   &                          \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{Risk D}} & \multirow{-2}{*}{*}          & \multirow{-2}{*}{}         & \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}{\color[HTML]{9B9B9B} }} & \multirow{-2}{*}{...} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}}} & \multirow{-2}{*}{...}    \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                         &                              &                            & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}}                                                                                                               &                          \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{Risk E}} & \multirow{-2}{*}{}           & \multirow{-2}{*}{*}        & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}}}                                                                                             & \multirow{-2}{*}{...}    \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: IN your MWE (Minimal Working Example) are missed packages. Please, complete it that will become compilable.

Comment: Your code is not compileable.

Comment: Please add `\usepackage{multirow,float}` to your source code, then it will be compileable.

Comment: Code is now compileable

Comment: Here is a solution that uses tikz code on top of a regular table in order to shade cells or fill them with a hatched pattern: [Set table background hatched and shaded using tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/67096/134144)