# Partially coloring cell background with histograms

Tags: tables, color, backgrounds

Excel has a cool feature called "data bar" conditional formatting that allows the user to partially fill a cell background to create histograms based on cell contents.  Here is a screen clip example from a workbook:

[image: example]

I'm looking for a TiKZ, minipage, or some other solution that will allow me to only partially color the background of a cell.  I've played around with a few options without success.

Here is a minimum working example using `\cellcolor` from the `xcolor` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l|c|r}
  \hline
  91.41 & \cellcolor{green!25}90.81 & 38.76 \\
  \cellcolor{green!25}98.75 & 13.82 & 94.62 \\
  57.11 & \cellcolor{green!25}51.21 & \cellcolor{green!25}42.84 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The code above produces:

[image: mwe-example]

In a perfect world, I'd have a macro like `\partialcellcolor{green!25}{0.41\linewidth}` or whatever to specify that the color extends across `41%` of the cell.  I use "`R`" to generate the table, so I'll let it do the math as it scripts the latex code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I guess this question was asked before but right now I can only find [gradient-color-in-one-cell-of-a-table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59227/gradient-color-in-one-cell-of-a-table)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I've rewritten this whole answer. For the previous version, see [the history of this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/81998/6).

For this, the columntype `H` is introduced that takes one possibly empty argument.

For positive numbers the bar is filled from left to right, for negative nmbers the bar is filled from right to left.

They values `min`, `max`, `min neg`, `max neg` need
to be set to scale the bar. The `max neg` value is initialized with `0` as it is used to determine the width of the node which is needed for `align=right` to work. (There are [other ways](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121054/16595) to do this but I'm keeping it simple.)

I don't think it makes much sense to set `min` and `min neg` to something other than `0` but the option is there.

Various styles can be used to change the appearence. Hopefully, these are self-explanatory.

This is how the table is ultimately specified:

```
\begin{tabular}{
  | H{} | H{min=2.00,max=105.00}
  | H{max neg=-10.00, max=15.00, add format={precision=0}}|}
  \hline
   10    &   2    & -10 \\
   15.49 &  13.82 &  -5 \\
  100    & 105    &   5 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
```

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,array,collcell}
\newcommand*\tikzcellbgset{\pgfqkeys{/tikz/cellbg}}
\tikzcellbgset{
  /pgf/number format/.code=\pgfqkeys{/pgf/number format}{#1},
  node/.style={
    /pgf/number format={/tikz/cellbg/number format},
    node contents={\strut\pgfmathprintnumber{#1}},
    anchor=base, outer sep=+0pt, inner ysep=+0pt, align=right,
    inner xsep=\tabcolsep,
    /utils/exec=%
      \pgfmathprintnumberto{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/cellbg/max}}{\tempa}%
      \pgfmathprintnumberto{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/cellbg/max neg}}{\tempb},
    text width/.expanded={max(width("\tempa"),width("\tempb"))},
    path picture={
      \def\tcbgvo########1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/cellbg/########1}}% Eugh!
      \pgftransformshift
        {\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{south west}}
      \pgfsetxvec{%
        \pgfpointdiff
          {\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{south west}}
          {\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{south east}}}
      \pgfsetyvec{%
        \pgfpointdiff
          {\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{south west}}
          {\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{north west}}}
      \pgfmathifthenelse{#1<0}{"0"}{"1"}
      \ifnum\pgfmathresult=0
        \path[cellbg/fill neg](1,0) rectangle
          ++({-(#1-\tcbgvo{min neg})/(\tcbgvo{max neg}-\tcbgvo{min neg})},1);
      \else
        \path[cellbg/fill pos](0,0) rectangle
          ({(#1-\tcbgvo{min})/(\tcbgvo{max}-\tcbgvo{min})},1);
      \fi
  }},
  max/.initial=100, min/.initial=0,
  max neg/.initial=0, min neg/.initial=0,
  pos color/.code=\colorlet{@tikz@cellbg@pos}{#1},
  neg color/.code=\colorlet{@tikz@cellbg@neg}{#1},
  fill pos/.style={fill=@tikz@cellbg@pos}, pos color=green!25,
  fill neg/.style={fill=@tikz@cellbg@neg}, neg color=red!50,
  number format/.style={fixed zerofill},
  add format/.style={/tikz/cellbg/number format/.append style={#1}}
}
\newcommand{\tikzMe}[1]{\tikz[baseline,cellbg/pic/.try]\node[cellbg/node={#1}];}
\newcolumntype{H}[1]{%
  @{}>{\tikzcellbgset{#1}\collectcell\tikzMe}c<{\endcollectcell}@{}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{
  | H{} | H{min=2.00,max=105.00}
  | H{max neg=-10.00, max=15.00, add format={precision=0}}|}
  \hline
   10    &   2    & -10 \\
   15.49 &  13.82 &  -5 \\
  100    & 105    &   5 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: This is a great example of how to keep the data section of the table clean by using the `array` package embed all the logic in the column types.  Thanks!

Comment: I've been thinking about how to encode `\maxValue` on a column-by-column basis.  For example, `\begin{tabular}{|L|C|R|}` might look like: `\begin{tabular}{|L{0}{100}|C{-20}{120}|R{0}{100}|} where 2 arguments (min and max column range) are included on a column-by-column basis.

Comment: I switched my "answered" to your solution.  THANKS!  This is really, really cool!

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel How can column header row be used with text in it...?

Comment: @ADP Usually, you can use `\multicolumn{1}` to escape any column specification (including `\collectcell`).

Comment: This example does not work for me. I get "! Undefined control sequence.
\minWidth ->\widthof 
                     {$\ifnegativeValues -\fi 100.00$}
l.40     10.0   &
                  2.00   & 0.00   \\"

Comment: @nobody TikZ brings its own `width` measuring function that can be used. `\widthof` can just be replaced with `width`. However, I've updated the answer to a more user-friendly and expandable approach.

Answer (score 30):

Another sans-TikZ alterantive:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fp
\newcommand{\maxnum}{100.00}
\newlength{\maxlen}
\newcommand{\databar}[2][green!25]{%
  \settowidth{\maxlen}{\maxnum}%
  \addtolength{\maxlen}{\tabcolsep}%
  \FPeval\result{round(#2/\maxnum:4)}%
  \rlap{\color{green!25}\hspace*{-.5\tabcolsep}\rule[-.05\ht\strutbox]{\result\maxlen}{.95\ht\strutbox}}%
  \makebox[\dimexpr\maxlen-\tabcolsep][r]{#2}%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{*{3}{|l}|}
  \hline
  \databar{91.41} & \databar {90.81} & \databar{38.76} \\
  \databar{98.75} & \databar {13.82} & \databar{94.62} \\
  \databar{57.11} & \databar {51.21} & \databar{42.84} \\
  \databar{20.00} & \databar{100.00} & \databar{80.00} \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

You provide the maximum number (as a macro `\maxnum`) that is used to calculate the percentage fill. Calculations are performed using [`fp`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fp).

---

Using this variation of `\databar` provides a fill that leaves a (barely visible) `.5\arrayrulewidth` on either side of the table cell. This is just to avoid any kind of artefacts caused by the viewer. The TikZ solution doesn't show this since it draws the coloured boxes in the background (almost as an underlay) of the entire table, so the rules overdraw any overlap:

[image]

```
%...
\newcommand{\databar}[2][green!25]{%
  \settowidth{\maxlen}{\maxnum}%
  \addtolength{\maxlen}{\dimexpr2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}%
  \FPeval\result{round(#2/\maxnum:4)}%
  \rlap{\color{green!25}\hspace*{\dimexpr-\tabcolsep+.5\arrayrulewidth}\rule[-.05\ht\strutbox]{\result\maxlen}{.95\ht\strutbox}}%
  \makebox[\dimexpr\maxlen-2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth][r]{#2}%
}
%...
```

Comment: Can this answer be modified so that the 100% bars stretch the full width of the cell (and others proportionally)?

Comment: @Sparr: I've added that to my answer. I've still kept a small (`.5\arrayrulewidth`) gap between the box and the `tabular` rules, since a reader may show an "overlap", although this is actually not the case. If you really don't want that, you can remove any reference to `\arrayrulewidth` in the updated version of `\databar`.

Comment: @Werner: It was hard to pick, but I have to go with your non-Tikz option. Thanks!!!!  I'm going to play with this base code so that the maximum value in each column is used to scale the histograms.  This version hard codes `\maxnum` to `100`, but in my working code I'll need to use  `\maxnum` over all the values in a given column.

Comment: @JohnLeonard: That can be achieved using the [`array` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) and specifying a new column type that takes the "maximum value" as an argument.

Comment: I have adapted this solution to use a custom maximum width as my column header was quite a bit wider than the maximum number; works like a charm :)

Comment: You have "green!25" as the default, but "#1" is not used. Instead, you repeat "green!25", which ignores the parameter.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper post your solution.

Comment: I've tried to adapt your code in R, thank you for posting such a great example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46595296/r-markdown-pdf-partially-color-cell-background-data-bar/47085376#47085376

Comment: And here is another different one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623866/creating-r-tables-with-embedded-graphics/47119715#47119715

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{collcell}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{B}{>{\collectcell\BarValue}c<{\endcollectcell}}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\BarValue}{m}
  {
    #1
    \tl_gput_right:Nx \g_nicematrix_code_before_tl
      { 
        \__pantigny_bar_value:nnn 
          { \int_use:c { c@iRow } } 
          { \int_use:c { c@jCol } } 
          { \fp_eval:n { #1 / 100 } } 
      }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__pantigny_bar_value:nnn 
  {
    \tikz \fill [blue!15] 
          (#1-|#2) 
          rectangle 
          ( $ ( \int_eval:n { #1 + 1 } -| #2 )
              ! #3 !
              ( \int_eval:n { #1 + 1 } -| \int_eval:n { #2 + 1 } ) $ )
    ; 
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{NiceTabular}{BBB}[hvlines,first-col]
A & 40.89 & 80.5 & 38.76 \\
B & 90.89 & 70 & 15.76 \\
C & 57.11 & 21.21 & 92.84 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

I ultilize TikZ's ability for this: simple and flexible!

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\tab[2]{%
\begin{scope}[shift={(-.5,.5)}]
\fill[green!20] #1 rectangle +(#2/100,-1); 
\draw #1 rectangle +(1,-1);
\end{scope}
\path #1 node{#2};
}% end of tab

\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=.5,xscale=1.2]
\tab{(0,0)}{40.89}  \tab{(1,0)}{80.5}   \tab{(2,0)}{38.76}
\tab{(0,-1)}{90.89} \tab{(1,-1)}{70}    \tab{(2,-1)}{15.76}
\tab{(0,-2)}{57.11} \tab{(1,-2)}{21.21} \tab{(2,-2)}{92.84}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting solution, but if you have to add a column between two existing columns, you have to manually modify the absolute position of all the columns on the right (or on the left) of the one you're adding.

Comment: @CarLaTeX you are right! The beauty come first ^^ I think it's acceptable for small tables

Comment: Yes, for small tables is surely acceptable.