# Change cellcolor automatically according to the number in cell – "dimension too large"

Tags: tables, cellcolor

I would like to change cell color based on the values.
I found  code from another post
[Change cellcolor automaticly acording to the number in cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281822/change-cellcolor-automaticly-acording-to-the-number-in-cell/281828#281828)

Here is the code that works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{booktabs}

% This selects the amount of color to use
\newcommand*{\MinNumber}{0}%
\newcommand*{\MaxNumber}{150}%

\newcommand{\ApplyGradient}[1]{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{100.0*(#1-\MinNumber)/(\MaxNumber-\MinNumber)}%
  %\textcolor{black!\PercentColor}{#1}
  \edef\x{\noexpand\cellcolor{green!\PercentColor}}\x\textcolor{black}{#1}%
}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\collectcell\ApplyGradient}{r}<{\endcollectcell}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}{
\begin{tabular}{ c R R R R R R R R}
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{1}{c} {Tools} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c} {D1} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c} {D2} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c} {D3} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c} {D4} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c} {D5} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c} {D6} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c} {D7} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c} {D8} \\
  A &   150 &    80.81 &   54.5 & 100 & 51 & 8&  99 & 90\\
  B &   66 &     99 &   73 & 0 & 66 &  59&  88 & 60\\
  \toprule
\end{tabular}
}{}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I changed the numbers and I get an error when I use larger numbers. Specifically, I changed the \MaxNumber to 250
and the first number in the tabular table to 200. The number 200 in the table causes the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{booktabs}

% This selects the amount of color to use
\newcommand*{\MinNumber}{0}%
\newcommand*{\MaxNumber}{250}%

\newcommand{\ApplyGradient}[1]{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{100.0*(#1-\MinNumber)/(\MaxNumber-\MinNumber)}%
  %\textcolor{black!\PercentColor}{#1}
  \edef\x{\noexpand\cellcolor{green!\PercentColor}}\x\textcolor{black}{#1}%
}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\collectcell\ApplyGradient}{r}<{\endcollectcell}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}{
\begin{tabular}{ c R R R R R R R R}
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{1}{c} {Tools} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c} {D1} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c} {D2} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c} {D3} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c} {D4} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c} {D5} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c} {D6} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c} {D7} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c} {D8} \\
  A &   200 &    80.81 &   54.5 & 100 & 51 & 8&  99 & 90\\
  B &   66 &     99 &   73 & 0 & 66 &  59&  88 & 60\\
  \toprule
\end{tabular}
}{}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The error message is

```
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
! Dimension too large.
<recently read> \pgfmath@x
```

This is my first post. I am not sure whether I was supposed to comment on the other post or ask a separate question.  But because my "reputation" is below 50, I was not allowed to comment anyways.

Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.