# Partially colored cells

Tags: tables, color, cell

I would like to make partially colored cells as is shown in the answers here [Partially coloring cell background with histograms](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81994/partially-coloring-cell-background-with-histograms).

TikZ example does not work for me and I would rather use the answer without TikZ.

The problem I have is that I have column headers and then the coloring does not start at the left border of the cell any more.

Here is an minimal working example I have made from the answer above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fp
\newlength{\maxlen}
\newcommand{\databar}[3][green!50]{%
  \settowidth{\maxlen}{#2}%
  \addtolength{\maxlen}{\dimexpr2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}%
  \FPeval\result{round(#3/#2:4)}%
  \rlap{\color{#1}\hspace*{\dimexpr-\tabcolsep+.5\arrayrulewidth}\rule[-.05\ht\strutbox]{\result\maxlen}{.95\ht\strutbox}}%
  \makebox[\dimexpr\maxlen-2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth][r]{#3}%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ | l | r |}
  \hline
  Name & Value column which is much wider \\
  \hline
  name1 & \databar{10.0}{1} \\
  name2 & \databar{10.0}{2} \\
  name3 & \databar{10.0}{3} \\
  name4 & \databar{10.0}{4} \\
  name5 & \databar{10.0}{5} \\
  name6 & \databar{10.0}{6} \\
  name7 & \databar{10.0}{8} \\
  name8 & \databar{10.0}{8} \\
  name9 & \databar{10.0}{9} \\
  name10 & \databar{10.0}{10} \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Wide column]

I would like the bars to extend over the whole column and not just on the right side of it. How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: For one thing, change the column alignment of the second column from `r` to `l`.  The other thing is that the column width is driven by the column title width, not the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\newlength\maxlen
\newcommand\databar[3][green!50]{%
  \FPeval\result{round(#3/#2:4)}%
  \rlap{\textcolor{#1}{\hspace*{\dimexpr-\tabcolsep+.5\arrayrulewidth}%
        \rule[-.05\ht\strutbox]{\result\maxlen}{.95\ht\strutbox}}}%
  \makebox[\dimexpr\maxlen-2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth][r]{#3}}
\def\header{Value column which is much wider}
\settowidth\maxlen{\header}
\addtolength\maxlen{\dimexpr2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{ | l | l |}
        \hline
        Name & \header \\
        \hline
        name1 & \databar{10.0}{1} \\
        name2 & \databar{10.0}{2} \\
        name3 & \databar{10.0}{3} \\
        name4 & \databar{10.0}{4} \\
        name5 & \databar{10.0}{5} \\
        name6 & \databar{10.0}{6} \\
        name7 & \databar{10.0}{8} \\
        name8 & \databar{10.0}{8} \\
        name9 & \databar{10.0}{9} \\
        name10 & \databar{10.0}{10} \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Now I see that the width of actual text is taken to get the width of the cells. What if I want to use two or more columns of different widths to display the databars?

Comment: eg.: `\def\header{Name\hspace{2\tabcolsep}Value column which is much wider}`. For a p-column you can set it to the width of the p column