# Coloring a Multicolmn

Tags: color, multicolumn

I am trying to color the following table:

```
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c|c| }
\hline
1,5h&               0,25h&   13h&    0,25h& 0,5h \\ \hline
Flight preparation& Taxiing& Flight& Taxiing&   Flight debrief \\ \hline
&   \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Block time}&   \\ \hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Duty time} \\  \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Goal:

1. To make the cell "BLOCK TIME" in the color yellow.
2. To make the cell "DUTY TIME" in green.

Please note, I do not want to color a complete row or column. Just the CELL!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) is the preferred way here to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Related total overkill: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59227/36821

Answer (score 3):

You can just load the `xcolor` package and use `\cellcolor{color}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}    % loads also »colortbl«

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c|c| }
\hline
1,5h&               0,25h&   13h&    0,25h & 0,5h \\ \hline
Flight preparation& Taxiing& Flight& Taxiing&   Flight debrief \\ \hline
&  \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\cellcolor{yellow} Block time} &   \\ \hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\cellcolor{green}  Duty time} \\  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: or just colortbl:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You're right... Never thought about that: is loading just the other package better? I feel like loading too much if this includes multiple purposes... and thanks!

Comment: No xcolor is a nice package and probably people using colour will use it anyway and no one but me minds which package defines which feature, but \cellcolor comes from colortbl:-) (actually it was Donald Arseneau who suggested it)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see. Thanks for the info! :)