# Moving table with \newpage, but cellcolors stay behind

Tags: tables, page-breaking

I'm trying to apply the code in
[Gradient color in one cell of a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59227/gradient-color-in-one-cell-of-a-table)

However, when I want to put the table on the next page with `\newpage`, the colors stay behind, while the table moves.

See this picture:
[image]

How can I make the colors move along with the table when I use `\newpage`?

**Adapted code**

This is the code after I added `\newpage`

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry} % just for the example 
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shadings}

% Andrew Stacey's code from
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50054/3954
\makeatletter
\tikzset{%
    remember picture with id/.style={%
        remember picture,
        overlay,
        save picture id=#1,
    },
    save picture id/.code={%
        \edef\pgf@temp{#1}%
        \immediate\write\pgfutil@auxout{%
            \noexpand\savepointas{\pgf@temp}{\pgfpictureid}}%
    },
    if picture id/.code args={#1#2#3}{%
        \@ifundefined{save@pt@#1}{%
            \pgfkeysalso{#3}%
        }{
            \pgfkeysalso{#2}%
        }
    }
}

\def\savepointas#1#2{%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname save@pt@#1\endcsname{#2}%
}

\def\tmk@labeldef#1,#2\@nil{%
    \def\tmk@label{#1}%
    \def\tmk@def{#2}%
}

\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{pic}{%
    \pgfutil@in@,{#1}%
    \ifpgfutil@in@%
    \tmk@labeldef#1\@nil
    \else
    \tmk@labeldef#1,(0pt,0pt)\@nil
    \fi
    \@ifundefined{save@pt@\tmk@label}{%
        \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone\tmk@def
    }{%
        \pgfsys@getposition{\csname save@pt@\tmk@label\endcsname}\save@orig@pic%
        \pgfsys@getposition{\pgfpictureid}\save@this@pic%
        \pgf@process{\pgfpointorigin\save@this@pic}%
        \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
        \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
        \pgf@process{\pgfpointorigin\save@orig@pic}%
        \advance\pgf@x by -\pgf@xa
        \advance\pgf@y by -\pgf@ya
    }%
}
\newcommand\tikzmark[2][]{%
    \tikz[remember picture with id=#2] {#1;}}
\makeatother
% end of Andrew's code

\newcommand\ShadeCell[4][0pt]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]%
    \shade[#4] ( $ (pic cs:#2) + (0pt,2ex) $ ) rectangle ( $ (pic cs:#3) + (0pt,-#1*\baselineskip-.8ex) $ );
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\begin{document}

    \ShadeCell[14]{start1}{end1}{%
        shading=color wheel white center,opacity=.15}
    \ShadeCell{start2}{end2}{%
        left color=red!20,right color=green!20}
    \ShadeCell[13]{start3}{end3}{%
        top color=green!20,bottom color=red!20}
    \ShadeCell{start4}{end4}{%
        left color=blue!20,right color=green!20}
    \newpage
    \begin{tabular}{| l | p{6cm} | c |}
        \hline
        Uncolored cell 
        & \multicolumn{1}{!{\tikzmark{start1}} p{6cm} !{\vrule\tikzmark{end1}}}{\lipsum*[2]} 
        & Uncolored cell \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{!{\vrule\tikzmark{start2}} l !{\vrule\tikzmark{end2}}}{Another colored cell} 
        & Another uncolored cell & Another uncolored cell \\
        \hline
        Uncolored cell 
        & \lipsum[4] 
        & \multicolumn{1}{!{\tikzmark{start3}} c !{\vrule\tikzmark{end3}}}{Another colored cell} \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{!{\vrule\tikzmark{start4}} c !{\vrule\tikzmark{end4}}}{Another merged colored cell}
        & Uncolored cell \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

**Original code and the original picture** (from [Gradient color in one cell of a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59227/gradient-color-in-one-cell-of-a-table))

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry} % just for the example 
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shadings}

% Andrew Stacey's code from
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50054/3954
\makeatletter
\tikzset{%
  remember picture with id/.style={%
    remember picture,
    overlay,
    save picture id=#1,
  },
  save picture id/.code={%
    \edef\pgf@temp{#1}%
    \immediate\write\pgfutil@auxout{%
      \noexpand\savepointas{\pgf@temp}{\pgfpictureid}}%
  },
  if picture id/.code args={#1#2#3}{%
    \@ifundefined{save@pt@#1}{%
      \pgfkeysalso{#3}%
    }{
      \pgfkeysalso{#2}%
    }
  }
}

\def\savepointas#1#2{%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname save@pt@#1\endcsname{#2}%
}

\def\tmk@labeldef#1,#2\@nil{%
  \def\tmk@label{#1}%
  \def\tmk@def{#2}%
}

\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{pic}{%
  \pgfutil@in@,{#1}%
  \ifpgfutil@in@%
    \tmk@labeldef#1\@nil
  \else
    \tmk@labeldef#1,(0pt,0pt)\@nil
  \fi
  \@ifundefined{save@pt@\tmk@label}{%
    \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone\tmk@def
  }{%
  \pgfsys@getposition{\csname save@pt@\tmk@label\endcsname}\save@orig@pic%
  \pgfsys@getposition{\pgfpictureid}\save@this@pic%
  \pgf@process{\pgfpointorigin\save@this@pic}%
  \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
  \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
  \pgf@process{\pgfpointorigin\save@orig@pic}%
  \advance\pgf@x by -\pgf@xa
  \advance\pgf@y by -\pgf@ya
  }%
}
\newcommand\tikzmark[2][]{%
\tikz[remember picture with id=#2] {#1;}}
\makeatother
% end of Andrew's code

\newcommand\ShadeCell[4][0pt]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]%
    \shade[#4] ( $ (pic cs:#2) + (0pt,2ex) $ ) rectangle ( $ (pic cs:#3) + (0pt,-#1*\baselineskip-.8ex) $ );
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\begin{document}

\ShadeCell[14]{start1}{end1}{%
  shading=color wheel white center,opacity=.15}
\ShadeCell{start2}{end2}{%
  left color=red!20,right color=green!20}
\ShadeCell[13]{start3}{end3}{%
  top color=green!20,bottom color=red!20}
\ShadeCell{start4}{end4}{%
  left color=blue!20,right color=green!20}

\begin{tabular}{| l | p{6cm} | c |}
\hline
Uncolored cell 
  & \multicolumn{1}{!{\tikzmark{start1}} p{6cm} !{\vrule\tikzmark{end1}}}{\lipsum*[2]} 
  & Uncolored cell \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{!{\vrule\tikzmark{start2}} l !{\vrule\tikzmark{end2}}}{Another colored cell} 
  & Another uncolored cell & Another uncolored cell \\
\hline
Uncolored cell 
  & \lipsum[4] 
  & \multicolumn{1}{!{\tikzmark{start3}} c !{\vrule\tikzmark{end3}}}{Another colored cell} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{!{\vrule\tikzmark{start4}} c !{\vrule\tikzmark{end4}}}{Another merged colored cell}
  & Uncolored cell \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please post a minimal working example (code sample with *necessary* packages and *minimal* code) to help us help you.

Comment: you have forced a page break between the colours and the table, just put the `\newpage` before the colours, not after.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Would you like to convert your comment into an answer?

Comment: @samcarter done:)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you! One questions less on the list of unanswered :)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

You have forced a page break between the colours and the table, just put the `\newpage` before the colours, not after.