# Color gradient in the table

Tags: color, tabulary

How can I make a color gradient in a table from the first row to the last row (from top to bottom)?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
  width = \linewidth,
  colspec = {Q[165]Q[165]Q[165]Q[165]},
  cells = {c},
  row{1} = {blue!50},
  row{2} = {cyan!50},
  hlines,
  vlines}
 a & B & C & D \\
one & two & three & noone
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59227/gradient-color-in-one-cell-of-a-table?rq=1 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174998/are-there-an-easy-way-to-coloring-tables-depending-on-the-value-in-each-cell

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` with a row by row color gradient (you need several compilations).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{c}
\CodeBefore
   \definecolorseries{BlueWhite}{rgb}{last}{blue}{white}
   \resetcolorseries[\value{iRow}]{BlueWhite}
   \rowlistcolors{1}{BlueWhite!!+}
\Body
Mathilde \\
Pierre \\
Paul \\
Amélie \\
Jacques \\
Antoine \\
Stéphanie \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the first code]

Here is an example with a continuous gradient (Tikz must be loaded).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{c}[color-inside]
\Block[tikz = {top color=blue, bottom color=white}]{*-*}{}
Mathilde \\
Pierre \\
Paul \\
Amélie \\
Jacques \\
Antoine \\
Stéphanie \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]

In both cases, the instructions automatically take into account the number of row and columns of the tabular.