# Coloring lines in an algorithm

Tags: errors, color, algorithms, algorithmicx

I am using Beamer for creating a presentation and I am trying to highlight some lines in an algorithm. I am actually using `algcompatible`.

I found a solution [here](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&p=67058) and created a couple of new commands to highlight some code lines in an algorithm, based on that solution:

```
\newcommand{\algcolor}[2]{\hspace*{-\fboxsep}\colorbox{#1}{\parbox{\linewidth}{#2}}}
\newcommand{\algemph}[1]{\algcolor{GreenYellow}{#1}}
```

That works pretty well, but it is failing in some cases, depending on the lines that I want to highlight. For instance, the following algorithm works fine:

```
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \FORALL{$elem$ in $collection$}
        \STATE $foo(elem)$
        \algemph{\STATE $bar(elem)$}
    \ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}
```

But, if I swap the two statements in the loop:

```
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \FORALL{$elem$ in $collection$}
        \algemph{\STATE $bar(elem)$}
        \STATE $foo(elem)$
    \ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}
```

I get this error when calling `pdflatex`:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                  \ALG@currentblock@2 
l.19 \end{frame}
```

Here you have a minimal reproducible test case:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor} % prevent an option clash
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{algcompatible}

\newcommand{\algcolor}[2]{\hspace*{-\fboxsep}\colorbox{#1}{\parbox{\linewidth}{#2}}}
\newcommand{\algemph}[1]{\algcolor{GreenYellow}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test Frame}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \FORALL{$elem$ in $collection$}
            \algemph{\STATE $bar(elem)$}
            \STATE $foo(elem)$
        \ENDFOR
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Is it possible to fix the current approach that I am using? Is there any other solution for coloring lines in an algorithm?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's one possible solution using (oh, surprise!) the improved version of `\tikzmark` provided by Andrew Stacey in [`his answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50054/3954) to [tikzmark to have different behaviour if first run (and mark locations not yet available)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50015/3954).

The idea is to define a new family of loops and declarations, totally analogous to the ones provided by `algcompatible`, but adding automatically the colored background; for each command of the form `\X` now you have the corresponding command `\CX` (prepending a capital `C` to the original name) which automatically handles the color; for example, now you have the standard `\STATE` command and the colored version `\CSTATE`; the functionality and syntax of each `\CX` command is exactly the same as that of its corresponding `\X` command.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{algcompatible}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
% code borrowed from Andrew Stacey; See
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50054/3954
\tikzset{%
  remember picture with id/.style={%
    remember picture,
    overlay,
    save picture id=#1,
  },
  save picture id/.code={%
    \edef\pgf@temp{#1}%
    \immediate\write\pgfutil@auxout{%
      \noexpand\savepointas{\pgf@temp}{\pgfpictureid}}%
  },
  if picture id/.code args={#1#2#3}{%
    \@ifundefined{save@pt@#1}{%
      \pgfkeysalso{#3}%
    }{
      \pgfkeysalso{#2}%
    }
  }
}

\def\savepointas#1#2{%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname save@pt@#1\endcsname{#2}%
}

\def\tmk@labeldef#1,#2\@nil{%
  \def\tmk@label{#1}%
  \def\tmk@def{#2}%
}

\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{pic}{%
  \pgfutil@in@,{#1}%
  \ifpgfutil@in@%
    \tmk@labeldef#1\@nil
  \else
    \tmk@labeldef#1,(0pt,0pt)\@nil
  \fi
  \@ifundefined{save@pt@\tmk@label}{%
    \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone\tmk@def
  }{%
  \pgfsys@getposition{\csname save@pt@\tmk@label\endcsname}\save@orig@pic%
  \pgfsys@getposition{\pgfpictureid}\save@this@pic%
  \pgf@process{\pgfpointorigin\save@this@pic}%
  \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
  \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
  \pgf@process{\pgfpointorigin\save@orig@pic}%
  \advance\pgf@x by -\pgf@xa
  \advance\pgf@y by -\pgf@ya
  }%
}

\makeatother
% end of Andrew's code

% main command to draw the colored background
\newcounter{mymark}
\newcommand\ColorLine{%
  \stepcounter{mymark}%
  \tikz[remember picture with id=mark-\themymark,overlay] {;}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
    \filldraw[GreenYellow]%
   let \p1=(pic cs:mark-\themymark), 
   \p2=(current page.east)  in 
   ([xshift=-0.3em,yshift=-0.7ex]0,\y1)  rectangle ++([xshift=-1.2cm]\x2,\baselineskip);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}%

% colored loops and declarations
\makeatletter
\algnewcommand\CREQUIRE{\item[\ColorLine\algorithmicrequire]}%
\algnewcommand\CENSURE{\item[\ColorLine\algorithmicensure]}%
\algnewcommand\CSTATE{\State\ColorLine}%
\algnewcommand\CSTATEx{\Statex\ColorLine}%
\algnewcommand\CCOMMENT{\Comment\ColorLine}%

\algdef{SE}[WHILE]{CWHILE}{ENDWHILE}%
   [2][default]{\ColorLine\algorithmicwhile\ #2\ \algorithmicdo\ALG@compatcomm{#1}}%
   {\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicwhile}%
\algdef{SE}[FOR]{CFOR}{ENDFOR}%
   [2][default]{\ColorLine\algorithmicfor\ #2\ \algorithmicdo\ALG@compatcomm{#1}}%
   {\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicfor}%
\algdef{S}[FOR]{CFORALL}%
   [2][default]{\ColorLine\algorithmicforall\ #2\ \algorithmicdo\ALG@compatcomm{#1}}%
\algdef{SE}[LOOP]{CLOOP}{ENDLOOP}%
   [1][default]{\ColorLine\algorithmicloop\ALG@compatcomm{#1}}%
   {\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicloop}%
\algdef{SE}[REPEAT]{CREPEAT}{UNTIL}%
   [1][default]{\ColorLine\algorithmicrepeat\ALG@compatcomm{#1}}%
   [1]{\algorithmicuntil\ #1}%
\algdef{SE}[IF]{CIF}{ENDIF}%
   [2][default]{\ColorLine\algorithmicif\ #2\ \algorithmicthen\ALG@compatcomm{#1}}%
   {\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicif}%
\algdef{C}[IF]{IF}{CELSIF}%
   [2][default]{\ColorLine\algorithmicelse\ \algorithmicif\ #2\ \algorithmicthen\ALG@compatcomm{#1}}%
\algdef{Ce}[ELSE]{IF}{CELSE}{ENDIF}%
   [1][default]{\ColorLine\algorithmicelse\ALG@compatcomm{#1}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test Frame 1}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\CREQUIRE Some initial values
\ENSURE Some conditions
\CLOOP
  \STATE$bar(elem)$
  \STATE$baz(elem)$
  \CFOR{$quality\ge 9$}
    \STATE$a\gets perfect$
    \CSTATE$a\gets unusable$
  \ENDFOR
\ENDLOOP
\end{algorithmic}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Test Frame 2}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\REQUIRE Some initial values
\CENSURE Some conditions
\FORALL{$elem$ in $collection$}
  \STATE$bar(elem)$
  \CSTATE$foo(elem)$
  \STATE$baz(elem)$
  \CIF{$quality\ge 9$}
    \STATE$a\gets perfect$
  \ELSE
    \CSTATE$a\gets unusable$
  \ENDIF
\ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The images of the obtained document:

[image]

[image]

The document has to be processed twice.

And here's a little variation in which the background colored stripes have uniform length:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{algcompatible}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
% code borrowed from Andrew Stacey; See
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50054/3954
\tikzset{%
  remember picture with id/.style={%
    remember picture,
    overlay,
    save picture id=#1,
  },
  save picture id/.code={%
    \edef\pgf@temp{#1}%
    \immediate\write\pgfutil@auxout{%
      \noexpand\savepointas{\pgf@temp}{\pgfpictureid}}%
  },
  if picture id/.code args={#1#2#3}{%
    \@ifundefined{save@pt@#1}{%
      \pgfkeysalso{#3}%
    }{
      \pgfkeysalso{#2}%
    }
  }
}

\def\savepointas#1#2{%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname save@pt@#1\endcsname{#2}%
}

\def\tmk@labeldef#1,#2\@nil{%
  \def\tmk@label{#1}%
  \def\tmk@def{#2}%
}

\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{pic}{%
  \pgfutil@in@,{#1}%
  \ifpgfutil@in@%
    \tmk@labeldef#1\@nil
  \else
    \tmk@labeldef#1,(0pt,0pt)\@nil
  \fi
  \@ifundefined{save@pt@\tmk@label}{%
    \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone\tmk@def
  }{%
  \pgfsys@getposition{\csname save@pt@\tmk@label\endcsname}\save@orig@pic%
  \pgfsys@getposition{\pgfpictureid}\save@this@pic%
  \pgf@process{\pgfpointorigin\save@this@pic}%
  \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
  \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
  \pgf@process{\pgfpointorigin\save@orig@pic}%
  \advance\pgf@x by -\pgf@xa
  \advance\pgf@y by -\pgf@ya
  }%
}

% end of Andrew's code

\newlength\AlgIndent
\setlength\AlgIndent{0pt}
% main command to draw the colored background
\newcounter{mymark}
\newcommand\ColorLine{%
  \stepcounter{mymark}%
  \tikz[remember picture with id=mark-\themymark,overlay] {;}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
    \filldraw[GreenYellow]%
   let \p1=(pic cs:mark-\themymark), 
   \p2=(current page.east)  in 
   ([xshift=-\ALG@thistlm-0.3em,yshift=-0.7ex]0,\y1)  rectangle ++(\linewidth+\AlgIndent,\baselineskip);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}%

% colored loops and declarations
\algnewcommand\CREQUIRE{\item[\setlength\AlgIndent{1.6em}\ColorLine\algorithmicrequire]}%
\algnewcommand\CENSURE{\item[\setlength\AlgIndent{1.6em}\ColorLine\algorithmicensure]}%
\algnewcommand\CSTATE{\State\ColorLine}%
\algnewcommand\CSTATEx{\Statex\ColorLine}%
\algnewcommand\CCOMMENT{\Comment\ColorLine}%

\algdef{SE}[WHILE]{CWHILE}{ENDWHILE}%
   [2][default]{\ColorLine\algorithmicwhile\ #2\ \algorithmicdo\ALG@compatcomm{#1}}%
   {\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicwhile}%
\algdef{SE}[FOR]{CFOR}{ENDFOR}%
   [2][default]{\ColorLine\algorithmicfor\ #2\ \algorithmicdo\ALG@compatcomm{#1}}%
   {\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicfor}%
\algdef{S}[FOR]{CFORALL}%
   [2][default]{\ColorLine\algorithmicforall\ #2\ \algorithmicdo\ALG@compatcomm{#1}}%
\algdef{SE}[LOOP]{CLOOP}{ENDLOOP}%
   [1][default]{\ColorLine\algorithmicloop\ALG@compatcomm{#1}}%
   {\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicloop}%
\algdef{SE}[REPEAT]{CREPEAT}{UNTIL}%
   [1][default]{\ColorLine\algorithmicrepeat\ALG@compatcomm{#1}}%
   [1]{\algorithmicuntil\ #1}%
\algdef{SE}[IF]{CIF}{ENDIF}%
   [2][default]{\ColorLine\algorithmicif\ #2\ \algorithmicthen\ALG@compatcomm{#1}}%
   {\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicif}%
\algdef{C}[IF]{IF}{CELSIF}%
   [2][default]{\ColorLine\algorithmicelse\ \algorithmicif\ #2\ \algorithmicthen\ALG@compatcomm{#1}}%
\algdef{Ce}[ELSE]{IF}{CELSE}{ENDIF}%
   [1][default]{\ColorLine\algorithmicelse\ALG@compatcomm{#1}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test Frame 1}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\CREQUIRE Some initial values
\ENSURE Some conditions
\CLOOP
  \STATE$bar(elem)$
  \STATE$baz(elem)$
  \CFOR{$quality\ge 9$}
    \STATE$a\gets perfect$
    \CSTATE$a\gets unusable$
  \ENDFOR
\ENDLOOP
\end{algorithmic}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Test Frame 2}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\REQUIRE Some initial values
\CENSURE Some conditions
\FORALL{$elem$ in $collection$}
  \STATE$bar(elem)$
  \CSTATE$foo(elem)$
  \STATE$baz(elem)$
  \CIF{$quality\ge 9$}
    \STATE$a\gets perfect$
  \ELSE
    \CSTATE$a\gets unusable$
  \ENDIF
\ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is really great! It does exactly what I needed. Just one question, some colored tags (such as CENDFOR) are not defined, so it is impossible to color a whole for loop. It is not a big deal since, `end for` has not too much information, but it could be useful sometimes. I was thinking to add a new definition such as: `\algdef{SE}[FOR]{CFOR}{CENDFOR}%
   [2][default]{\ColorLine\algorithmicfor\ #2\ \algorithmicdo\ALG@compatcomm{#1}}%
   {\ColorLine\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicfor}%`. Would that be the correct way to implement coloring for `end for`?

Comment: @betabandido yes, that's the correct way.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Any idea how to make this work correctly for lines like `\State$a$\gets$\max_x f(x)$`, where the subscript extends below the "normal" height of the line? Other than that it works great!

Comment: @3lectrologos I did some tests using the code you proposed (fixing some typos): `\CSTATE$a\gets\max_x f(x)$` and the colored stripe covers the text with no problems; if you are experiencing something different, please open a fresh new question as a [follow-up questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117)  to this one; don't forget to add a MWE to the new question, allowing us to replicate the problem.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina OK, I'll do that if I can't figure it out. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 7):

The following definition of `\algemph` works, but should be used in the following way:

```
\STATE \algemph{<stuff>}
```

[image]

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor} % prevent an option clash
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{algcompatible}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\algcolor}[2]{%
  \hskip-\ALG@thistlm\colorbox{#1}{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{\hskip\ALG@thistlm\relax #2}}%
}
\newcommand{\algemph}[1]{\algcolor{GreenYellow}{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test Frame}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \FORALL{$elem$ in $collection$}
      \STATE $foo(elem)$
      \STATE \algemph{$bar(elem)$}
    \ENDFOR
    \FORALL{$elem$ in $collection$}
      \STATE \algemph{$bar(elem)$}
      \STATE $foo(elem)$
    \ENDFOR
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The logical approach is to set the line number *first* (which in the case of [`algorithmicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx)) includes the indent. `\algemph` subsequently skips back (horizontally), and then sets the coloured box (with the required indentation re-inserted).