# How to make a hbox several lines under the specified place?

Tags: macros, color, line-breaking, algorithms, algorithm2e

Recently I asked [How to colourfuly highlight some lines of an algorithm using algorithm2e?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/149779/17444)

I wanted to acheive this effect using the `algorithm2e` package:

[image]

Thanks to [JLDiaz's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/149855/17444) I know how to do it. JLDiaz suggests that I define a macro using the `xcolor` package like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e} % http://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e
\usepackage{xcolor} % http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor

% This is the solution:
\def\HiLi{\leavevmode\rlap{\hbox to 
\hsize{\color{yellow!50}\leaders\hrule height .8\baselineskip depth .5ex\hfill}}}


\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[h]
 \caption{Evolutionary algorithm}
 initialize population \;
 \HiLi\For( \emph{Evolutionary loop}){$g := 1$ to $G_{max}$}
 {
    \HiLi do things \;
    evolve population \;
 }
 celebrate \;
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that there is no way how to **paint the end statement**.

I have never done any LaTeX programming, but I think that a solution could be to
make a similar macro that would place a hbox at the place where it is called and an identical hbox a few lines later. The number of lines could be provided manually.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible, but it requires some hacking at the internal code of `algorithm2e.sty`.

Add the following lines inside your `algorithm` if you want this behavior locally, or in the preamble if you want it to be global:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\algocf@@@block}[2]{#1\ifArgumentEmpty{#2}{\relax}{\KwSty{\HiLi\@algocf@endoption{#2}}\strut\par}}
\makeatother
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e} % http://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e
\usepackage{xcolor} % http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor

% This is the solution:
\def\HiLi{\leavevmode\rlap{\hbox to
\hsize{\color{yellow!50}\leaders\hrule height .8\baselineskip depth .5ex\hfill}}}


\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[h]
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\algocf@@@block}[2]{#1\ifArgumentEmpty{#2}{\relax}{\KwSty{\HiLi\@algocf@endoption{#2}}\strut\par}}
\makeatother
 \caption{Evolutionary algorithm}
 initialize population \;
 \HiLi\For( \emph{Evolutionary loop}){$g := 1$ to $G_{max}$}
 {
    \HiLi do things \;
    evolve population \;
 }
 celebrate \;
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]