# How to highlight sections of my code in algorithm?

Tags: algorithm2e

- I have picture below I want my paper look like that.
- I have sample code below but the highlight doesnt fill up to the left margin and there is whitespace in between.
- I have been trying very long but keep failing.
- Point 2 is not addressed in this post [How can I colourfuly highlight some lines of an algorithm using algorithm2e?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149779/how-can-i-colourfuly-highlight-some-lines-of-an-algorithm-using-algorithm2e) SO THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e} % http://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e
\usepackage{xcolor} % http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor

\def\HiLi{\leavevmode\rlap{\hbox to \hsize{\color{yellow!50}\leaders\hrule height .8\baselineskip depth .5ex\hfill}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[h]
 \caption{Evolutionary algorithm}
 initialize population \;
 \HiLi\For( \emph{Evolutionary loop}){$g := 1$ to $G_{max}$}
 {
    \HiLi do things \;
    evolve population \;
 }
 celebrate \;
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

The code gives me the image below. How can i fill up the highlight to the left margin like in the 1st picture and remove the whitespace between highlights ?

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would do this using TikZ. The idea is to use TikZ to mark the top and bottom of the region to be marked, and then use a boxing macro which uses the `fit` library to make a node that fits the marked nodes, with the width calculated automatically.

Because this uses the `[remember picture]` functionality of TikZ, two compilations will be needed to get the boxes in their correct position.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e} % http://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e
\usepackage{xcolor} % http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc}
%define a marking command
\newcommand*{\tikzmk}[1]{\tikz[remember picture,overlay,] \node (#1) {};\ignorespaces}
%define a boxing command, argument = colour of box
\newcommand{\boxit}[1]{\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\node[yshift=3pt,fill=#1,opacity=.25,fit={(A)($(B)+(.95\linewidth,.8\baselineskip)$)}] {};}\ignorespaces}
%define some colours according to algorithm parts (or any other method you like)
\colorlet{mypink}{red!40}
\colorlet{myblue}{cyan!60}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[h]
 \caption{Evolutionary algorithm}
 initialize population \;
 \tikzmk{A}\For( \emph{Evolutionary loop}){$g := 1$ to $G_{max}$}
 {
    do things \;
    evolve population \;
 }\tikzmk{B}
 \boxit{mypink}
 celebrate \;
 \tikzmk{A}\For( \emph{Evolutionary loop}){$g := 1$ to $G_{max}$}
 {
    do things \;
    evolve population \;
 }\tikzmk{B}
 \boxit{myblue}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]