# Highlight Lines in side-by-side algorithm

Tags: color, algorithms, ieeetran, highlighting, algorithmic

I have a 2 column latex template (IEEEtran), in which I put 2 algorithms side by side:

```
\documentclass[10pt,conference]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\HiLi{\leavevmode\rlap{\hbox to \hsize{\color{yellow!50}\leaders\hrule height .8\baselineskip depth .5ex\hfill}}}
\begin{document}


\begin{figure*}[htbp]
\centering
 \begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
    
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
        \caption{Foo}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \REQUIRE $Beer$
            \HiLi \STATE $s \leftarrow HighlightThis$
            \STATE $f \leftarrow Foo()$

        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
 \end{minipage}
 \begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
    
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
        \caption{Bar}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \REQUIRE $Wine$\\
            \STATE $s \leftarrow Bar()$
            \STATE $b \leftarrow Bar1()$
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
    \vfill
 \end{minipage}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

My goal is to highlight the line "HighlightThis". I've tried these 2: [Approach1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149779/how-can-i-colourfuly-highlight-some-lines-of-an-algorithm-using-algorithm2e), [TikZ Approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386272/how-to-highlight-sections-of-my-code-in-algorithm).

The problem is with both approaches, the highlight gets completely misplaced:
Approach 1 result:
[image]

How can this be done?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Please tell us how or where `\HiLi` is defined.

Comment: @Mico this comes from the mentioned approach 1, I edited the question to make the code compilable, including the approach. I mainly need one of the approaches to work, I can also gladly use TikZ if it's possible then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're going for?

[image]

I changed the \HiLi command to use \linewidth instead of \hsize and moved the \HiLi command placement in the algorithm. See below:

```
\documentclass[10pt,conference]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\HiLi{\leavevmode\rlap{\hbox to \linewidth{\color{yellow!50}\leaders\hrule height .8\baselineskip depth .5ex\hfill}}}
\begin{document}


\begin{figure*}[htbp]
\centering
 \begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
    
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
        \caption{Foo}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \REQUIRE $Beer$
            \STATE \HiLi $s \leftarrow HighlightThis$
            \STATE $f \leftarrow Foo()$
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
 \end{minipage}
 \begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
    
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
        \caption{Bar}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \REQUIRE $Wine$\\
            \STATE $s \leftarrow Bar()$
            \STATE $b \leftarrow Bar1()$
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
    \vfill
 \end{minipage}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes! Well, like 99%... If I use this on a if-else, only the conditional check gets highlighted, not the "if" itself...

Comment: Not sure. Probably need to play around with the \HiLi command...

Comment: @dv3 Can you add a MWE for that case?

Comment: @Anush it's vitalstatistix code, but applied not only to a state line, but also to a \IF line...