# Coloring the lines of an algorithm

Tags: color, algorithm2e, highlighting

I'm writing a report for a class project and I need to highlight several lines within some of the algorithms in the report. I managed to do so, but I don't like the solution I got. Here is a picture (see code of MWE below).

[image]

To get this, I used `\color{red}`, then put the text I wanted to highlight, followed by `\color{black}`. I wonder if I can highlight in red the same lines of the algorithm but not the line numbers and also not the comment `a miracle in polynomial time`. What solutions are there for this? [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64674/coloring-lines-in-an-algorithm) proposes redefining commands of the package but they are not using the same package as I am, and I wonder whether it can be made more simply or not.

If I could be given advice on how to do this, while sticking to the package `algorithm2e`, as far as it is possible, that would be great.

**Code**:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\pdfoutput=1
\usepackage[linesnumbered,titlenumbered,ruled,vlined,resetcount,algosection]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
\title{MWE}
\maketitle
\section{Algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{3-SAT in polynomial time}
    \label{alg:hs}
    \DontPrintSemicolon
    \KwIn{List of clauses}
    \KwOut{The clauses are satisfiable}
    \SetKwProg{Fn}{Function}{ is}{end}
    \Fn{\textsc{IsSatisfiable}($C$)} {
    
        \color{red} %<- my best attempt
        $k\gets 0$ \;
        \For {$i = 1$ \bf{to} $|C|$}
        {
            $c_i \gets $ $i$-th clause \;
            $L \gets$ list of literals of $c_i$ \;
            $k\gets f(k, L)$ \tcp{a miracle in polynomial time}
        }
        \color{black} %<- go back to color black
        
        \If {$k$ is even} {
            \Return true
        }
        \Else {
            \Return false
        }
        
    }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've never used `algorithm2e` but looking at its documentation (Sec. 9.5.3) I'd say the most sensible thing is to redefine the fonts for the numbers and comments to explicitly include a directive to switch the color to `black`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[linesnumbered,titlenumbered,ruled,vlined,resetcount,algosection]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}

%% These three lines  !!!
\SetNlSty{textbf}{\color{black}}{}
\newcommand*{\mycommentfont}[1]{\textcolor{black}{\ttfamily#1}}
\SetCommentSty{mycommentfont}

\begin{document}
\title{MWE}
\maketitle
\section{Algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{3-SAT in polynomial time}
    \label{alg:hs}
    \DontPrintSemicolon
    \KwIn{List of clauses}
    \KwOut{The clauses are satisfiable}
    \SetKwProg{Fn}{Function}{ is}{end}
    \Fn{\textsc{IsSatisfiable}($C$)} {
        \begingroup
        \color{red}
        $k\gets 0$ \;
        \For {$i = 1$ \bf{to} $|C|$}
        {
            $c_i \gets $ $i$-th clause \;
            $L \gets$ list of literals of $c_i$ \;
            $k\gets f(k, L)$ \tcp{a miracle in polynomial time}
        }
        \endgroup            
        \If {$k$ is even} {
            \Return true
        }
        \Else {
            \Return false
        }
        
    }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The extra definition of `\mycommentfont` is necessary because the font commands of `algorithm2e` expect a single macro name (without `\`) of a macro taking one argument.

Comment: Oh, wow! What a simple solution. I could've never come up with this, thank you!