# Is it possible to use tikz to draw a background on the printed page?

Tags: tikz-pgf, backgrounds

Imagine I want to draw a filled shape behind something already typeset in the page. The usual approach is to define a `\tikzmark` command which simply remembers a coordinate using `remember picture` and `overlay` options, and later use that coordinate to draw tikz stuff using transparency.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\def\tikzmark#1{\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\coordinate(#1);}
\begin{document}
\noindent\tikzmark{A}\lipsum[11]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \fill[yellow, opacity=.3] (A) circle(2em);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image: Result]

But now assume that I want a *solid* yellow. The obvious idea is to use `pgfonlayer` and draw it on the background. However, the concept of background/foreground apparently only exists inside tikz environments. Since the main text in the page was already typeset, it is behind tikz's background:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\def\tikzmark#1{\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\coordinate(#1);}
\begin{document}

\noindent\tikzmark{A}\lipsum[11]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \fill[yellow] (A) circle(2em);
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Bad]

Can it be done?

Comment: The usual approach to putting things behind the page is to add the picture to the page head then it will be typeset first

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you. But that approach is incompatible with `\tikzmark` trick. You can't use in the header the absolute coordinates of a node which will be defined later via `\tikzmark`, because the node is unknown yet.

Comment: You could use `\pdfsavepos` and store the position in the aux-file. The `marginnote` package uses this method to place the notes. And the `zref` package has a module `savepos` which you could use.

Comment: @JLDiaz Yes you can.  Use the *new improved* `tikzmark`.  Functionally, this is the same as the suggestions that Ulrike makes but it's designed to be used with TikZ so is probably the better choice if you want to use TikZ to do the drawing.

Comment: Doesn't tikzmark just use pdfsavemark internally, I'd assumed it does (but don't really know anything about tikz) also the page header is executed _after_ the page contents (but placed earlier in the output when the output routine assembles the page, so I don't see why it should not work)

Comment: @AndrewStacey Thank you very much! I have write a self-answer just in case this can be useful to someone who is searching for "background" and "tikz" (I had not found your new `\tikzmark` using this search!)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You are right, putting it in header should work. However I've found a nicer solution using `background` package.

Comment: Yes saw in chat, yes background uses the everypage package which basically does the same thing but in a bit more structured way

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Thanks to Andrew Stacey for pointing me to the *new improved `tikzmkark`*. I was not aware of it. This version of `\tikzmark` allows for using the defined coordinates *before* the point of its definition. Using `\tikzmark{foo}` a new coordinate named `(pic cs:foo)` is available and can be used anywhere in the page.

Using the new `\tikzmark`, taken from the preamble of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50054/12571 the problem can be solved like this:

```
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \fill[yellow] (pic cs:A) circle(2em);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\tikzmark{A}\lipsum[11]
\end{document}
```

With the desired result:

[image: Good]

## Appendix

For completeness, the code of the whole document, including the preamble in which the new `\tikzmark` appears, is included here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{%
  remember picture with id/.style={%
    remember picture,
    overlay,
    save picture id=#1,
  },
  save picture id/.code={%
    \edef\pgf@temp{#1}%
    \immediate\write\pgfutil@auxout{%
      \noexpand\savepointas{\pgf@temp}{\pgfpictureid}}%
  },
  if picture id/.code args={#1#2#3}{%
    \@ifundefined{save@pt@#1}{%
      \pgfkeysalso{#3}%
    }{
      \pgfkeysalso{#2}%
    }
  }
}

\def\savepointas#1#2{%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname save@pt@#1\endcsname{#2}%
}
\def\tmk@labeldef#1,#2\@nil{%
  \def\tmk@label{#1}%
  \def\tmk@def{#2}%
}

\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{pic}{%
  \pgfutil@in@,{#1}%
  \ifpgfutil@in@%
    \tmk@labeldef#1\@nil
  \else
    \tmk@labeldef#1,(0pt,0pt)\@nil
  \fi
  \@ifundefined{save@pt@\tmk@label}{%
    \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone\tmk@def
  }{%
  \pgfsys@getposition{\csname save@pt@\tmk@label\endcsname}\save@orig@pic%
  \pgfsys@getposition{\pgfpictureid}\save@this@pic%
  \pgf@process{\pgfpointorigin\save@this@pic}%
  \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
  \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
  \pgf@process{\pgfpointorigin\save@orig@pic}%
  \advance\pgf@x by -\pgf@xa
  \advance\pgf@y by -\pgf@ya
  }%
}
\newcommand\tikzmark[2][]{%
\tikz[remember picture with id=#2] #1;}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \fill[yellow] (pic cs:A) circle(2em);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\tikzmark{A}\lipsum[11]
\end{document}
```

**NOTE**: Anyone inclined to vote for this self-answer, should vote for https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50054/12571 instead :-)

---

## Update

As noted by Ulrike Fischer in a comment, putting the `tikzpicture` which draws the background too close to the decorated paragraph can have side effects on previous paragraph:

```
\begin{document}
\lipsum[5] % <------ Added a previous paragraph
\medskip
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \fill[yellow] (pic cs:A) circle(2em);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\tikzmark{A}\lipsum[11]
\end{document}
```

[image: Bad :-(]

However, separating too much the `tikzpicture` from the `\tikzmark` we risk ending with those in separate pages, and thus the background will appear in the wrong page.

The best solution is then to use some solution which "stores" the required picture and "activates" its output as background at same time that we place the `\tikzmark`, as for example the solution proposed by Ulrike in the comment.

I explored another option, which is to use the wonderful [background package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/background) by [Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3954/gonzalo-medina) (thanks to Andrew for suggesting it in a chat!). Using this package we set-up the background picture anywhere in the document, and "activate" it with `\BgThispage` at same time that we place the `\tikzmark`. Using this approach there is no need for the *new improved `tikzmark`* and instead the *old minimalistic `tikzmark`* can be used.

It is important also to give appropiate values to options `placement` and `scale`, in order to get the drawing at the appropiate coordinates. There is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[pages=some]{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\def\tikzmark#1{\tikz[remember picture, overlay]\coordinate(#1);}

\begin{document}
\backgroundsetup{scale=1,placement=bottom,contents={%
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \fill[yellow] (A) circle(2em);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}}

\lipsum[5]
\medskip
\noindent\tikzmark{A}\BgThispage\lipsum[11]
\end{document}
```

And after three (why three?) compilations I get:

[image: Good!]

Comment: It doesn't work if the `\tikzmark` is on another page than the `tikzpicture`, and if you keep the tikzpicture near the `\tikzmark` the picture can overwrite text above if it isn't at the start of the page. So you probably should define a special page style, put the picture in the header and use `\thispagestyle{special}\tikzmark{A}`.

Comment: Sadly I'm unable to vote for the linked answer so I'll vote for this one instead.

Comment: You could also use the `tikzmark` library (browse the code at [launchpad.net](https://code.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development)): this will simplify your life in the appendix (besides providing other useful extras).