# Measure upper left and bottom right of text with zref

Tags: zref

i want to get the position of the upper left of a text and the position of the bottom right of a text. right now i'm using the following code which works ok for images but not for text because it breaks the textflow (see image below. remark: the border illustrates the rectangle created by the two measured points and is not in the actual output)

[image]

```
\begin{tabular}{c c c}
\zlabel{Overlay\arabic{overlay}} \zsavepos{Overlay\arabic{overlay}1} & & \\
& Testquery test test test & \\
& & \zsavepos{Overlay\arabic{overlay}2}\\
\end{tabular}
```

How can i improve the code above and avoid that the textflow gets interrupted?

Comment: `\zsavepos` uses `\pdfsavepos` to save the location *on the baseline* of where it's placed. You're creating a tabular that has 3 rows - you should only use one and adjust vertically the y-coordinate *from the baseline*. Can you show how you are creating the rectangle?

Comment: The rectangle is directly created from the the two points saved with \zsavepos by writing them into a file and then reading them in a Java PDF Viewer that displays the created PDF and overlays the rectangle at the given position. Anyway, using just one row wouldnt solve the problem with the textflow i think.

Answer (score 1):

This answer may not be suitable because, in addition to the *x*-position of the upper left and lower right, it only gives the *dz* of the text, that is, the *relative* change in *z* from the start of the phrase, rather than the absolute coordinates on the page.  It uses `tabto`, rather than `zref`.

I base this code on my answer at [Draw Tikz highlighting on the background of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203299/draw-tikz-highlighting-on-the-background-of-text/220067#220067), and while the result here may seem a bit cluttered, it is to show you in gory detail what is being done.

Here, the command `\Ohighlight{}` delimits the inline text that we wish to "measure".  The red text is it being set relative to the preexisting text (i.e., starting mid-line, with line-wraps, paragraphs, etc.)

At any point before `\Ohighlight` is called a second time, I can recall the *x*-coordinate of the beginning and ending of the text as well as the *dz* used by the text.  I create the macro `\demo` to show this.  It laps a rule of the height *dz* to the left; it then sets the box (in cyan color) that was measured, properly employing its mid-line starting point.  Underneath the set box, it indents to the beginning of the start of the text (`\tmpx`} and creates a rule over to the end of the text (`\tmpy`), showing that it remembers where the text began and ended.

Below this graphical demonstration, it prints the value of *dz*, *x1*, and *x2*.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newlength\svpi
\newsavebox\tmpbox
\usepackage{tabto}
\newcommand\Ohighlight[2][]{\color{cyan}%
  \tabto*{0in}\edef\tmpx{\TabPrevPos}\tabto*{\tmpx}%
  \setlength\svpi{\the\parindent}%
  \savebox\tmpbox{%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}\parindent\svpi%
    \tabto*{\tmpx}#2\strut%
  \end{minipage}}%
  {#2}%
  \vspace*{\dimexpr-\dp\tmpbox-\ht\tmpbox+\dp\strutbox}%
  \tabto*{\tmpx}\color{red}#2\unskip\color{black}\ %
  \edef\tmpy{\TabPrevPos}%
}
\textwidth=5in

\def\demo{\noindent\llap{%
  \rule[-\dp\strutbox]{3pt}{\dimexpr+\dp\tmpbox+\ht\tmpbox+\ht\strutbox}}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\usebox{\tmpbox}}\\
  \tabto{\tmpx}\rule{\dimexpr\tmpy-\tmpx\relax}{3pt}%
  \par dz=\the\dimexpr+\dp\tmpbox+\ht\tmpbox+\ht\strutbox; x1,x2: \tmpx, \tmpy}

\begin{document}
The original highlight is drawn over the text.
The original definition works over... 

Multi paragraphs, so my fix should try to as well.

\bigskip

Now here is my fix. \Ohighlight{The highlight is drawn under the text}
Does it work multiline?

\demo

multiline?
\Ohighlight{The highlight is drawn under the text The highlight is drawn under the text The highlight is drawn under the text The highlight is drawn under the text

A new paragraph}
And more...

\demo

\Ohighlight{short}

\demo
\end{document}
```

[image]