# using \tikzmark in beamer: new versions of packages break old functionality

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, nodes, tikzmark

**UPDATE (08/03/18): This issue has been fixed in the latest version of the tikzmark package.**  The workaround proposed by cfr, using `\beameroriginal` to redefine the `\tikzmark` inside beamer environments, has now been incorporated into the tikzmark package.  So this question now serves only a historical purpose.

---

Formerly, this worked, including with pgf version 3.0.1a:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{A SLIDE}
meaningless filler\tikzmark{a}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,>=latex,shorten >=1pt,->,remember picture]
    % old preferred syntax for using tikz marks inside tikz pictures
    \node (foo) at (1,-3) {\tikzmark{b}};

    % new preferred syntax for using tikz marks inside tikz pictures
    % \tikzmark{b}{(1,-3)}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,>=latex,shorten >=1pt,->,remember picture]
    \draw[black] (pic cs:a) -- (4,-3);
    \draw[black] (pic cs:b) -- (4,-3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Now I've updated some packages--presumably including beamer--and it fails with the error "Cannot parse this coordinate."  A little searching the interweb shows that the preferred way to use `\tikzmark` inside a tikzpicture is now `\tikzmark{b}{(1,-3)}`.  Yet this fails also with the same error:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{A SLIDE}
meaningless filler\tikzmark{a}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,>=latex,shorten >=1pt,->,remember picture]
    % old preferred syntax for using tikz marks inside tikz pictures
    % \node (foo) at (1,-3) {\tikzmark{b}};

    % new preferred syntax for using tikz marks inside tikz pictures
    \tikzmark{b}{(1,-3)}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,>=latex,shorten >=1pt,->,remember picture]
    \draw[black] (pic cs:a) -- (4,-3);
    \draw[black] (pic cs:b) -- (4,-3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

On the other hand, the problem seems to be local to beamer, because this works:

```
%\documentclass{beamer}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,tikzmark}

\begin{document}

%\begin{frame}\frametitle{A SLIDE}
meaningless filler\tikzmark{a}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,>=latex,shorten >=1pt,->,remember picture]
    % old preferred syntax for using tikz marks inside tikz pictures
    % \node (foo) at (1,-3) {\tikzmark{b}};

    % new preferred syntax for using tikz marks inside tikz pictures
    \tikzmark{b}{(1,-3)}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,>=latex,shorten >=1pt,->,remember picture]
    \draw[black] (pic cs:a) -- (4,-3);
    \draw[black] (pic cs:b) -- (4,-3);
\end{tikzpicture}

%\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

(And finally, for completeness, using `\node (foo) at (1,-3) {\tikzmark{b}};` in the article class, but with the new packages, also fails, perhaps as expected.)

I dread trawling through the beamer class files.  Is there something "obvious" I'm missing first?

Comment: Welcome! I don't think what you are attempting can possibly be expected to work. The nesting of `remember` and/or `overlay` seems deeply problematic.

Comment: The problem is not related to the use of `overlay` or `remember picture`: the error still occurs without them, and does not occur under the `article` documentclass.

Comment: Yes, I agree. You get the error anyway. That's because the definitions are changed in the Beamer class. `\tikzmark` is not the same as `\tikzmark` usually is. Otherwise, it would not be overlay aware. The `remember picture` just seems pointless. But the `overlay` doesn't seem coherent. I don't care if it works - it is completely illogical!

Answer (score 9):

Nested Ti*k*Z pictures are unsupported. Period. Sometimes they work, but they are expected to break.

`\tikzmark` creates a Ti*k*Z picture. Although it can now be used inside `tikzpicture` environments, it should not be used inside nodes inside `tikzpicture` environments.

The `tikzmark` library provides `\subnode{}{}` for such cases.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{A SLIDE}
  meaningless filler\tikzmark{a}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,>=latex,shorten >=1pt,->,remember picture]
    % this has never been preferred: \tikzmark shouldn't be used inside a tikzpicture with any syntax
    \node (foo) at (1,-3) {\subnode{b}{}};
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,>=latex,shorten >=1pt,->,remember picture]
    \draw[black] (pic cs:a) -- (4,-3);
    \draw[black] (b) -- (4,-3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: subnode]

However, you don't really need a `\subnode{}{}` because there is nothing else inside your main `\node {}`.

So you can just use

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{A SLIDE}
  meaningless filler\tikzmark{a}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,>=latex,shorten >=1pt,->,remember picture]
    % this has never been preferred: \tikzmark shouldn't be used inside a tikzpicture with any syntax
    \node (foo) at (1,-3) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,>=latex,shorten >=1pt,->,remember picture]
    \draw[black] (pic cs:a) -- (4,-3);
    \draw[black] (foo) -- (4,-3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I've used `\node ...` as it gives exactly the same result. But obviously `\coordinate` would be a more obvious choice here in most cases.

The use of `\tikzmark` inside Ti*k*Z pictures is, moreover, presumably not intended for use in pictures using the `remember picture, overlay` options. Note that the example in the manual does not include these options. In particular, `overlay` over `overlay` doesn't make any sense. You overlay the picture containing the mark and then overlay that with a picture referring to it. But the whole point of marks is their specific location, isn't it?

In any case, I can't get the `inside` syntax to work without those options either ....

## EDIT

I don't think the new syntax is designed to work in conjunction with the special code used for Beamer.

```
\renewcommand<>{\tikzmark}[2][]{\only#3{\beameroriginal{\tikzmark}[{#1}]{#2}}}
```

The library does this to make `\tikzmark` overlay-specification aware. It also then needs to ensure that `\tikzmark`s are tied to one particular slide within a Beamer frame

```
tikzmark suffix=-\the\beamer@slideinframe
```

and something goes wrong with the expansion so that Ti*k*Z tries to parse something like `{[}` as a node name ....

***If*** your frames do not use overlay specifications, so that a frame has only one slide (at least where you want to use this), you can use

```
\begin{frame}\frametitle{A SLIDE}
  meaningless filler\tikzmark{d}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,shorten >=1pt,->,remember picture,overlay]
    \beameroriginal{\tikzmark}{e}{(1,-3)}
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,>=latex,shorten >=1pt,->,remember picture]
    \draw[black] (pic cs:d) -- (4,-3);
    \draw[black] (pic cs:e) -- (4,-3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
```

However, this may break in the future since it is not, as far as I can tell, documented as an end-user macro.

I don't really see, though, how it can make sense to use `overlay` when creating a mark. It makes the mark disembodied. Maybe I don't see why this would be useful. Yes. But I don't see even how it might be coherent.

The examples in the manual make sense, because they don't do this. But, here, you are overlaying stuff on overlaid stuff in a way which I just don't understand.

Comment: "\tikzmark creates a TikZ picture. Hence, it should not be used inside a tikzpicture environment."  Its creator seems to think otherwise!  See the answer to this question ("The syntax inside a tikzpicture is...") http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295903/refer-to-a-node-in-tikz-that-will-be-defined-in-the-future-two-passes

Comment: @Quiggin Oh, I see. I didn't know that bit had been added. You still shouldn't use it inside a node, though. That has never been supported.

Comment: Did you actually read my question?  It shouldn't be used inside a node--yes, that's why I also included the latest syntax, `\tikzmark{b}{(1,-3)}`.  As I wrote in my original post, that works in the `article` document class, but not `beamer`.

Comment: @Quiggin Your original syntax used `\tikzmark` inside a node. That was never intended to work, as I understand it. That is, on the basis of what the package's author has said before. What is new is not a new syntax for an existing feature. It is a new feature. That is, now you can use `\tikzmark` inside a Ti*k*Z picture, whereas previously you couldn't.

Comment: Ok!  But the new feature evidently does not work within the `beamer` documentclass.  That's what I'd like an answer to.

Comment: @Quiggin Just email Loopspace the URL for this question/answer if an answer doesn't appear here shortly.

Comment: thanks.  The use of `\beameroriginal` is, for my purposes, sufficient (I was not aware of that command!).  If you think Loopspace will have more to add, I'll wait for his reply; otherwise I'm happy to accept your answer.

Comment: Also I should say: as far as I can tell, I do need all the overlays in the full (non-minimal) code.  It's very complicated, but basically I construct an elaborate tikz picture with a `\foreach` loop over tikzpictures.  But then I want to lay down a colored rectangle in the background of just part of it.  My solution is to tag the relevant nodes with tikzmarks, and then conceptually afterwards but programmatically prior, overlay the background.

Thanks again for pointing out `\beameroriginal`.

Comment: @Quiggin Why don't you just use the `backgrounds` library? If you nest `tikzpicture`s, you need to box them first to be safe. It sounds to me as if you are trying to use `tikzmark` rather than using layers in a `tikzpicture`. That is going to make life much harder. Just create the number of layers you need in the picture and draw on those. Then you can define things first and draw under them later.

Comment: @Quiggin You should wait. This is a hack. Loopspace will have a solution.

Comment: The `backgrounds` library is certainly more elegant!  That was my original design.  But I couldn't get it to work across *multiple* tikz pictures (which is necessitated by some other, perhaps sub-optimal, design choices I've made).  So I abandoned `backgrounds` for `\tikzmark`s, inspired by this post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86693/is-it-possible-to-use-tikz-to-draw-a-background-on-the-printed-page

Comment: Well, nobody can say without knowing more, of course, but it sounds to me as though you've designed a hard life for yourself ;).

Comment: Thanks, I had the same issue with newer packages. The solution was to simply replace ``tikzmark`` with ``subnode``, when used inside nodes inside pictures.