# Different output xelatex and lualatex (tikzpagenodes, tcolorbox and background packages involved)

Tags: graphics, xetex, errors, luatex

I am positioning an image on the top of the page of chapter openings. The image should fill all the page width. The code below is working fine with `LuaLaTeX`, but when I run it with `XeLaTeX` (it should be run 3 times to get proper positioning) the image is moved to the horizontal centre of the page.
For other reasons, I have to run the document with `XeLaTeX`. What should I change in the code to run with  `XeLaTeX` and obtain the output shown with `LuaLaTeX`?

**EDIT** Changed to use an example image. The header will change to respect the images show; but the effect of useing `XeLaTeX` is the same.

```
\documentclass{book}

%%% Include image in chapter opening
\RequirePackage{tikzpagenodes}
%%% fill rectangle with image uisng tcolorbox
%%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219424/2483
\RequirePackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
%%% For the background
%%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86702/2483
\usepackage[pages=some]{background}
\newlength{\bleendlength}
\setlength{\bleendlength}{5mm}
\newcommand{\chapimage}[1]{%
  \backgroundsetup{scale=1,placement=top,contents={
      \tikz[remember picture,overlay] {%
      \path[fill overzoom image=example-image-a, fill image opacity=1, path fading=east, fading angle=-30]
      ($(current page.north west)+(-\bleendlength, \bleendlength)$)
      rectangle
      ($(current page.north east)+(\bleendlength, -6cm)$);
    }
  }
}
}



\begin{document}
\chapter{My first chapter}
\label{cha:my-first-chapter}
\chapimage{}\BgThispage




\end{document}
```

Correct output with `LuaLaTeX`:
[image]

Incorrect output with `XeLaTeX`:
[image]

Comment: please make your example so that it can be tested on other computers.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to attach the image file!

Comment: There is certainly no need for an external picture. Use one of the example picture e.g. from the mwe package.

Comment: I added the use of an example image.

Comment: I wouldn't use the background package for tikz content, and certainly not for content involving page nodes. As muzimuzhi Z writes, the background material is inside a node in a  tikzpicture and this very difficult to control. Use e.g. the eso-pic package instead, or the new shipout hooks of latex-dev.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I changed the code to use `eso-pic`. But know I have a similar error when I introduced the `crop` package. See my question [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/559138/2483)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value passed to `background`'s option `contents` (stored in `\Background@Contents`) is already typeset inside a `tikzpicture`. And nesting `tikzpicture` is an undefined behavior. See the implementation of `\bg@material` in `background` v2.1, 2014/03/04:

```
\newcommand\bg@material{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,scale=\Background@Scale]
  \node[
    rotate=\Background@Angle,
    scale=\Background@Scale,
    opacity=\Background@Opacity,
    anchor=\Background@NodeAnchor,
    xshift=\Background@HShift,
    yshift=\Background@VShift,
    color=\Background@Color,
    inner sep=0pt
    ]
    at (\Background@Position) [\Background@Anchor]
      {\Background@Contents};
  \end{tikzpicture}}%
```

A brute attempt is to redefine `\bg@material`.

```
% this example produces the same output with pdftex, xetex, and luatex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, fadings}
\usepackage[pages=some]{background}

\newlength{\bleendlength}
\setlength{\bleendlength}{5mm}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\bg@material{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay] {%
    \path[fill overzoom image=example-image-a, fill image opacity=1, path fading=east, fading angle=-30]
    ($(current page.north west)+(-\bleendlength, \bleendlength)$)
    rectangle
    ($(current page.north east)+(\bleendlength, -6cm)$);
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{My first chapter}\label{cha:my-first-chapter}

\BgThispage
\end{document}
```

Nicer solutions range from better redefinition, using another background pacakge, to providing a special page style set by `\chapter` (suppose you want to have similar background effect per chapter title page).

Comment: As you suggested I another background package (`eso-pic`), but I still have a similar error when using the `crop` package. See my [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/559138/2483)