# different behaviour lualatex and xelatex using crop and tikzpagenodes pckages

Tags: xetex, luatex, crop, tikzpagenodes

Using the `tikzpagenodes` package to position elements in the page, I noticed that when loading the `crop` package, `XeLaTeX` and `LuaLaTeX` have different behaviour.

`XeLaTeX` incorrectly calculates the `current page node` coordinates. To get the correct coordinates the `current page node` should be shifted using `hoffset` and `voffset`.

The MWE below show, two rectangles covering the `current page node`. The blue one is the node calculated by `tikzpagenodes`; the red one has been shifted to have the correct rectangle with `XeLaTeX`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[
%
  paperwidth = 210mm, 
  paperheight = 270mm,
  includefoot,
  includemp,
  nomarginpar,
%  textwidth
%  textheight
% marginparwidth
% marginparsep
  inner = 19.2mm+10mm,
  outer = 19.2mm+10mm,
  top = 14.6mm,
  bottom = 10.8mm,
  bindingoffset = 5.4mm,
%  showcrop
]%
{geometry}

\usepackage%
[
cam,
width = 230mm,
height = 290mm,
center]%
{crop}

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\begin{document}
\tikz[remember picture,overlay] {%
\draw [blue,line width=2mm]
(current page.south west)
rectangle
(current page.north east)
;

\draw [red,line width=2mm]
($(current page.south west)+ (-\hoffset, \voffset)$)
rectangle
($(current page.north east)+ (-\hoffset, \voffset)$)
;
}%
\end{document}
```

Correct output with `LuaLaTeX`:

[image]

Incorrect output with `XeLaTeX`:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is caused by a typo in `pgf`'s driver file for xetex, and the problem has been reported to `pgf`, see https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/909. Package `crop` sets non-zero `\hoffset` and `\voffset`, which uncover the problem.

The following code snippet can be used as a short-term workaround.

```
% after tikz is loaded
\usepackage{iftex}

\makeatletter
\ifXeTeX
  \def\pgf@sys@pdf@mark@pos@pgfpageorigin{\pgfqpoint{\hoffset}{\voffset}}
\fi
\makeatother
```

A full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[
  paperwidth = 210mm, 
  paperheight = 270mm,
  includefoot,
  includemp,
  nomarginpar,
%  textwidth
%  textheight
% marginparwidth
% marginparsep
  inner = 19.2mm+10mm,
  outer = 19.2mm+10mm,
  top = 14.6mm,
  bottom = 10.8mm,
  bindingoffset = 5.4mm,
%  showcrop
]%
{geometry}

\usepackage[
  cam,
  width = 230mm,
  height = 290mm,
  center
]%
{crop}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{iftex}

\makeatletter
\ifXeTeX
  \def\pgf@sys@pdf@mark@pos@pgfpageorigin{\pgfqpoint{\hoffset}{\voffset}}
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]
  \draw [blue,line width=2mm]
    (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
\end{document}
```

[image]

PS: Node `current page` is directly provided by `tikz`, so there is no need to load `tikzpagenodes` package.