# Grey highlighted words

Tags: color

How can I make small, grey-highlighted code - `words` just like this one in this sentence. Is it possible to put some math in these boxes later? I tried to use soul package but I didn't manage to change the colour.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The command to change the colour of a highlight in `soul` is `\sethlcolor{}`. Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,soul}
\sethlcolor{lightgray}
\begin{document}
\hl{this text has a light grey background}
\end{document}
```

You may encounter some trouble with mathematics in that the highlight does not expand vertically to fit the full height of your math; i.e. it looks like this:

[image]

A solution in this case would be to put your math into a [Tikz](http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf) node. The following code is an MWE in which I create a command `\tikzhl` that implements a highlight in this fashion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*{\tikzhl}[1]{\tikz[baseline=(X.base)] \node[fill=lightgray] (X) {#1};}
\begin{document}
\tikzhl{$x^2+4$}
\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Note that this Tikz solution (unlike soul) does not support line breaks. See [How to "highlight" text/formulas with tikz?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46434/how-to-highlight-text-formulas-with-tikz) for more on implementing highlights with Tikz.

If you want the background to be a lighter shade of grey, change `lightgray` to `black!10`. Varying the number `10` between `0` and `100` will produce increasingly dark shades of grey.

In the Tikz solution, you can vary the amount of 'padding' around the edge of your text with the `inner sep=` option thus:

```
\newcommand*{\tikzhl}[1]{\tikz[baseline=(X.base)] \node[fill=black!10,inner sep=1pt] (X) {#1};}
```

Answer (score 18):

You could load the `xcolor` package and use that package's `\colorbox` macro. The argument of `\colorbox` can be both text and math material.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} % for 'lightgray' color
\begin{document}
\colorbox{lightgray}{word}

\colorbox{yellow}{abcde}

\colorbox{lime}{$a^2+b^2=c^2$}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

One way could be the `soulpos` package that support line breaks:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=80mm, paperheight=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soulpos}
\ulposdef{\hlc}[xoffset=1pt]{\mbox{\color{cyan!30}\rule[-.8ex]{\ulwidth}{3ex}}}
\begin{document}
Some math \hlc{$x^2+4$} and \hlc{some wonderfull text}. 
Need \hl{two} compilations.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Here http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-tricks-e.html#coltext is another macro for hyphenated background-colored text. It needs not two compilations.