# Align leaves of a tree

Tags: tikz-qtree

I have the following tree in which the left-most leave is out of sync:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{level 1+/.style={level distance=3\baselineskip}}
\tikzset{level 2+/.style={level distance=2\baselineskip}}
\tikzset{frontier/.style={distance from root=8\baselineskip}}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=left, anchor=north}}
\tikzset{every leaf node/.append style={text depth=0pt}}
\Tree[.S
       [.NP er\\he ]
       [.NP
         [.Det das\\the ]
         [.N Buch\\book ] ]
       [.NP
         [.Det der\\the ]
         [.N Frau\\woman ] ]
       [.V gibt\\gives ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I followed 
[aligning several trees to the baseline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163056/aligning-several-trees-to-the-baseline)
and added `\tikzset{every leaf node/.append style={text depth=0pt}}`, but this does not have any effect.

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to use the powerful [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) package (internally uses PGF/TikZ):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
  parent anchor=south, 
  child anchor=north,
  align=left,
  base=bottom
},
where n children=0{tier=word}{}
[S
  [NP [er\\he] ]
  [NP
    [Det [das\\the] ]
    [N [Buch\\book] ] 
  ]
  [NP
    [Det [der\\the] ]
    [N [Frau\\woman] ] 
  ]
  [V [gibt\\gives] ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To have all node contents centred, change align=left to align=center (of course, this can be done only for the leaves or on a oer case basis).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
  parent anchor=south, 
  child anchor=north,
  align=center,
  base=bottom
},
where n children=0{tier=word}{}
[S
  [NP [er\\he] ]
  [NP
    [Det [das\\the] ]
    [N [Buch\\book] ] 
  ]
  [NP
    [Det [der\\the] ]
    [N [Frau\\woman] ] 
  ]
  [V [gibt\\gives] ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The option `base=bottom` is, in fact, not required here since all your leaves have two lines.

Comment: This is the second answer that points me to `forrest'. I guess I have to switch. The manual looks highly complex ... Do you have an easy way to center all leave items? "Frau" looks strange since "woman" is wider. `tikz-qtree` does this in the same way. So this would have been my next question for `tikz-qtree`.

Comment: @StefanMüller change `align=left` to `align=center`. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @StefanMüller Answer edited. And yes, I think you should consider changing to `forest`; it's really amazing. The documentation might seem complex, but it has numerous examples illustrating the commands.