# Align all leaf nodes in tikz-qtree

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, trees, tikz-qtree

I am trying to reproduce this graph:

[image: leaf aligned]

I've read in `tikz-qtree` documentation that I need to compute the size from the root as a multiple of level distance, but I can get it to work. So far I have:

```
\documentclass[ twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,%1headlines,% letterpaper a4paper
            footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,abstractoff, % <--- obsolete, remove (todo)
            BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,%11pt,a4paper,%
            ngerman,american,%
            ]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{tikz-qtree,tikz-qtree-compat}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings,babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=left}]
  \tikzset{
    edge from parent/.style={
      draw,edge from parent
      path={(\tikzparentnode.south)-- +(0,-8pt)-| (\tikzchildnode)}
    },
%    level 2/.style={level distance=50pt},
%    frontier/.style={distance from root=150pt} % Align leaf nodes
  }

   \Tree [.S
             [.NP
                [.Rolls-Royce ] [.Motor ] [.Cars ] [.Inc ]
             ]
             [.VP
                [.said ]
                [.SBAR
                   [.NONE ]
                   [.S
                      [.NP [.it ] ]
                      [. VP
                         [.expects ]
                         [.S
                            [.NP
                               [.its ] [.U.S ] [. sales ]
                            ]
                            [.VP
                               [. to ]
                               [. VP
                                  [.remain ]
                                  [.ADJP [. steady ] ]
                                  [.PP
                                     [.at ]
                                     [.NP
                                        [.QP [.about ] [.1200 ] ]
                                        [.cars ]
                                     ]
                                  ]
                               ]
                            ]
                         ]
                      ]
                   ]
                ]
             ]
            ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But the result is this (does not fit the page):

[image: my result]

What I am doing wrong?

So far I tried this recomendations:

- [aligning several trees to the baseline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163056/aligning-several-trees-to-the-baseline)
- [Align leaves of a tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167865/align-leaves-of-a-tree)

Comment: Welcome! It is helpful if you can post a complete minimal example i.e. with the preamble etc. needed to compile the document so people don't have to guess which packages, which class, how big the paper is that the tree is going off of, etc.

Comment: Done! best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working now!

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\resizebox{1.3\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center}]
  \tikzset{
    edge from parent/.style={
      draw,edge from parent
      path={(\tikzparentnode.south)-- +(0,-8pt)-| (\tikzchildnode)}
    },
    frontier/.style={distance from root=350pt} % Align leaf nodes
  }

   \Tree [.S
             [.NP Rolls-Royce\\NNP Motor\\NNP Cars\\NNPS Inc\\NNP ]
             [.VP said\\VBD
                [.SBAR -NONE-
                   [.S
                      [.NP it\\PRP ]
                      [. VP expects\\VBZ
                         [.S
                            [.NP its\\PRP\$ U.S\\NNP sales\\NNS ]
                            [.VP to\\TO
                               [.VP remain\\VB
                                  [.ADJP steady\\JJ ]
                                  [.PP at\\IN
                                     [.NP
                                        [.QP about\\IN 1200\\CD ]
                                        cars\\NNS
                                     ]
                                  ]
                               ]
                            ]
                         ]
                      ]
                   ]
                ]
             ]
         ]
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{figure}
```

[image: Working!]

The problem was was adding as nodes the leafs like so:

```
[.NP [.Rolls-Royce ] [.Motor ] [.Cars ] [.Inc ] ]
% The correct way
[.NP Rolls-Royce Motor Cars Inc ]
```

**UPDATE**

Folowing the advice of *CFR* I've made a few adjustements:

- Removed `resizebox`
- Decrease font size to `tiny`
- Reducing distance between internal edges

The code and result:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\tiny
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center}]
  \tikzset{
    edge from parent/.style={
      draw,edge from parent
      path={(\tikzparentnode.south)-- +(0,-8pt)-| (\tikzchildnode)}
    },
    frontier/.style={distance from root=208pt}, % Align leaf nodes
    level 1+/.style={level distance=18pt} % Distance between levels
  }

   \Tree [.S
             [.NP Rolls-Royce\\NNP Motor\\NNP Cars\\NNPS Inc\\NNP ]
             [.VP said\\VBD
                [.SBAR -NONE-
                   [.S
                      [.NP it\\PRP ]
                      [. VP expects\\VBZ
                         [.S
                            [.NP its\\PRP\$ U.S\\NNP sales\\NNS ]
                            [.VP to\\TO
                               [.VP remain\\VB
                                  [.ADJP steady\\JJ ]
                                  [.PP at\\IN
                                     [.NP
                                        [.QP about\\IN 1200\\CD ]
                                        cars\\NNS
                                     ]
                                  ]
                               ]
                            ]
                         ]
                      ]
                   ]
                ]
             ]
         ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

**UPDATE #2**

I've made another small change in order to make it look more like the original. The `None` leaf should be at level 3, not aligned with the rest of the sentence. For that, the only change that needs to be made is:

```
[.SBAR [.none ]
% instead of 
[.SBAR NONE
```

Result:

[image: final]

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest Forest for the tree and `sidewaysfigure` for the placement?

First, the tree:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges,linguistics]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  forked edges,
  where n children=0{tier=terminus}{},
  [S
     [NP
       [Rolls-Royce\\NNP]
       [Motor\\NNP]
       [Cars\\NNPS]
       [Inc\\NNP]
     ]
     [VP
       [said\\VBD]
       [SBAR
         [-NONE-]
         [S
           [NP
             [it\\PRP]
           ]
           [VP
             [expects\\VBZ]
             [S
               [NP
                 [its\\PRP\$]
                 [U.S\\NNP]
                 [sales\\NNS]
               ]
               [VP
                 [to\\TO]
                 [VP
                   [remain\\VB]
                   [ADJP
                     [steady\\JJ]
                   ]
                   [PP
                     [at\\IN]
                     [NP
                       [QP
                         [about\\IN]
                         [1200\\CD]
                       ]
                       [cars\\NNS]
                     ]
                   ]
                 ]
               ]
             ]
           ]
         ]
       ]
     ]
   ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: Forest tree]

Even set sideways, the tree is too wide. Rather than scaling it, which should be a choice of last resort, it would be better to use a smaller font size, such as `\scriptsize` and to reduce the space between the nodes by changing `s sep`. Making these changes, the tree fits and will be more legible than one which was simply scaled. This is especially true if you are using optically sized fonts.

[image: fitting tree]

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,  footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,abstractoff,BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,ngerman,american]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[edges,linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
  \centering
  \scriptsize
  \begin{forest}
    forked edges,
    where n children=0{tier=terminus}{},
    for tree={
      s sep'=1pt,
    },
    [S
      [NP
        [Rolls-Royce\\NNP]
        [Motor\\NNP]
        [Cars\\NNPS]
        [Inc\\NNP]
      ]
      [VP
        [said\\VBD]
        [SBAR
          [-NONE-]
          [S
            [NP
              [it\\PRP]
            ]
            [VP
              [expects\\VBZ]
              [S
                [NP
                  [its\\PRP\$]
                  [U.S\\NNP]
                  [sales\\NNS]
                ]
                [VP
                  [to\\TO]
                  [VP
                    [remain\\VB]
                    [ADJP
                      [steady\\JJ]
                    ]
                    [PP
                      [at\\IN]
                      [NP
                        [QP
                          [about\\IN]
                          [1200\\CD]
                        ]
                        [cars\\NNS]
                      ]
                    ]
                  ]
                ]
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  \end{forest}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I resolved the problem of not fitting in the page with resizebox, but now I've tried your tip on reducing the font size, it is better. Regards!