# list of and add to toc mdframed objects

Tags: tikz-pgf, table-of-contents, mdframed

Bellow is some developed example solution I asked here
[tikz and mdframed + shadow drop and shading](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119195/tikz-and-mdframed-shadow-drop-and-shading)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcounter{exercise}
\newtheorem{myexercise}{Exercise}[section]
\tikzset{myshadow/.style={                             % custom shadow with tikz
         opacity=.85,
         shadow xshift=0.15,
         shadow yshift=-0.15,
         shade,
         shading=axis,
         shading angle=230}
         } 
\tikzstyle{titregris} =
[draw=gray, line width=1.0pt,% 
        text=white, rectangle,  
        right,minimum height=.7cm,
       double,
       shade,
              top color=blue!40,
              bottom color=blue!5,
              rounded corners=8pt,
               opacity=1,
                                     shadow xshift=0.15,
                                     shadow yshift=-0.15,
                                     shade,
                                     shading=axis,
                                     shading angle=30,
              drop shadow,
        ]
\tikzstyle{pointstyle} =
[draw=red, thick, fill=red,% 
        text=white, rectangle,  
        right,minimum height=.7cm,
       double,
       shade,
              top color=red,
              bottom color=blue!5,
              rounded corners=3pt,
              drop shadow
        ]        

\renewcommand*\theexercise{Exercise \textnumero\arabic{exercise}}
\makeatletter
\def\mdf@@exercisepoints{}%new mdframed key:
\define@key{mdf}{exercisepoints}{%
\def\mdf@@exercisepoints{#1}
}
\def\mdf@@fig{}%new mdframed key:
\define@key{mdf}{fig}{%
\def\mdf@@fig{#1}
}
\def\mdf@@title{}%new mdframed key:
\define@key{mdf}{title}{%
\def\mdf@@title{#1}
}


\mdfdefinestyle{exercisestyle}{%
middlelinewidth=1.2pt,roundcorner=5pt,linecolor=gray,
%apptotikzsetting={\tikzset{mdfbackground/.append style ={%
%shading = exersicebackground}}},
 apptotikzsetting={\tikzset{mdfbackground/.append style={top color=blue!40, bottom color=white}}},
innertopmargin=1.2\baselineskip,
skipabove={\dimexpr0.5\baselineskip+\topskip\relax},
skipbelow={-1em},
 shadow=true,
 shadowcolor=blue!35,
needspace=3\baselineskip,
frametitlefont=\sffamily\bfseries,
settings={\global\refstepcounter{exercise}},
singleextra={%
\node[titregris,xshift=1cm] at (P-|O) %
{~\mdf@frametitlefont{\theexercise}~\mdf@@title};
\ifdefempty{\mdf@@exercisepoints}%
{}%\node[fill=blue!40,font=\color{black},yshift=-51,circle,inner sep=1pt]
{\node[pointstyle,left,xshift=-1cm] at (P)%
{~\mdf@frametitlefont{\mdf@@exercisepoints pt.}~};},%
\ifdefempty{\mdf@@fig}%
{}%
{\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in node[fill=blue!40,circle,inner sep=1pt,font=\color{white}] at (P|-0,0.5*\y2+0.5*\y1)  {\mdf@@fig};}% 
},
firstextra={%
\node[titregris,xshift=1cm] at (P-|O) %
{~\mdf@frametitlefont{\theexercise}~};
\ifdefempty{\mdf@@exercisepoints }%
{}%
{\node[pointstyle,left,xshift=-1cm] at (P)%
{~\mdf@frametitlefont{\mdf@@exercisepoints points}~};},%
{\node[pointstyle, left,xshift=1cm]  {$\clubsuit$};}
},
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[style=exercisestyle,exercisepoints=10,fig=$\spadesuit$,title= example $E=mc^2$]
%\begin{myexercise}
 \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u\cos\psi -v\sin\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\sin\psi + v\cos\psi
        \end{align}
        For small angles the following approximation can be used:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}
%\end{myexercise}        
\end{mdframed}
\listoftheorems{myexercise}
\end{document}
```

almost everything can be passed, Now question is can there be "List of Exercise" and
"add to toc" commands? Yes thee is a  tocloft, but it needs command. With TiKZ this is discussed here [Adding TikZ code to TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21090/adding-tikz-code-to-toc) . Do i need to wrap mdframed environment with another command? or there can be a another way? p.s. I tryied to use ntheorem to create new theorem , but when i do printing of list theorems it is not pronted in utf-8..It seems conflict with fontencoding..there are broken LIRC commands and i gave up with ntheorem

**From here New Qestion starts:**
Sorry...I edited and rolled back original code...here is an code developed during discussion. Since that fancy 'suit' node gives problem, when frame splits on tho pages, in coe below i removed it being default. So user can pass 'right side suit fig', when he knows that environment is not splitting. Before if there was no use of this frame splitting was ok...in code below there appeared ne problem: environmet title is lost and only counter value is displayed.

here is a code:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{exercise}

\newtheorem{myexercise}{Exercise}[section]
\tikzset{myshadow/.style={                             % custom shadow with tikz
         opacity=.85,
         shadow xshift=0.15,
         shadow yshift=-0.15,
         shade,
         shading=axis,
         shading angle=230}
         } 
\tikzstyle{titregris} =
[draw=gray, line width=1.0pt,% 
        text=white, rectangle,  
        right,minimum height=.7cm,
       double,
       shade,
              top color=blue!40,
              bottom color=blue!5,
              rounded corners=8pt,
               opacity=1,
                                     shadow xshift=0.15,
                                     shadow yshift=-0.15,
                                     shade,
                                     shading=axis,
                                     shading angle=30,
              drop shadow,
        ]
\tikzstyle{pointstyle} =
[draw=red, thick, fill=red,% 
        text=white, rectangle,  
        right,minimum height=.7cm,
       double,
       shade,
              top color=red,
              bottom color=blue!5,
              rounded corners=3pt,
              drop shadow
        ]        

%\renewcommand*\theexercise{Exercise \textnumero\arabic{exercise}}
\makeatletter
\def\mdf@@exercisepoints{}%new mdframed key:
\define@key{mdf}{exercisepoints}{%
\def\mdf@@exercisepoints{#1}
}
\def\mdf@@fig{}%new mdframed key:
\define@key{mdf}{fig}{%
\def\mdf@@fig{#1}
}
\def\mdf@@title{}%new mdframed key:
\define@key{mdf}{title}{%
\def\mdf@@title{#1}
}


\mdfdefinestyle{exercisestyle}{%
middlelinewidth=1.2pt,roundcorner=5pt,linecolor=gray,
 apptotikzsetting={\tikzset{mdfbackground/.append style={top color=blue!40, bottom color=white}}},
innertopmargin=1.2\baselineskip,
skipabove={\dimexpr0.5\baselineskip+\topskip\relax},
skipbelow={-1em},
 shadow=true,
 shadowcolor=blue!35,
needspace=3\baselineskip,
frametitlefont=\sffamily\bfseries,
singleextra={%
\node[titregris,xshift=1cm] at (P-|O) %
{~\mdf@frametitlefont{Exercise~\textnumero\theexercise}~\mdf@@title};
\ifdefempty{\mdf@@exercisepoints}%
{}%\node[fill=blue!40,font=\color{black},yshift=-51,circle,inner sep=1pt]
{\node[pointstyle,left,xshift=-1cm] at (P)%
{~\mdf@frametitlefont{\mdf@@exercisepoints pt.}~};},%
\ifdefempty{\mdf@@fig}%
{}%
{\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in node[fill=blue!40,circle,inner sep=1pt,font=\color{white}] at (P|-0,0.5*\y2+0.5*\y1)  {\mdf@@fig};}% 
},
firstextra={%
\node[titregris,xshift=1cm] at (P-|O) %
{~\mdf@frametitlefont{\theexercise}~};
\ifdefempty{\mdf@@exercisepoints }%
{}%
{\node[pointstyle,left,xshift=-1cm] at (P)%
{~\mdf@frametitlefont{\mdf@@exercisepoints points}~};},%
%{\node[pointstyle, left,xshift=1cm]  {$\clubsuit$};}
},
}
\newcommand\listmdfname{List of Exercises}
\newcommand\listofmdframed{\section*{\listmdfname}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
              {\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
\@starttoc{mdf}}
\newenvironment{mythm}[2][]
  {\refstepcounter{exercise}\addcontentsline{mdf}{figure}{Exercise~\theexercise~#2}\begin{mdframed}[style=exercisestyle,#1,title=#2]}
  {\end{mdframed}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listofmdframed

\begin{mythm}[exercisepoints=10,fig=$\spadesuit$]{Example $E=mc^2$}
 \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u\cos\psi -v\sin\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\sin\psi + v\cos\psi
        \end{align}
        For small angles the following approximation can be used:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}
\end{mythm}

\begin{mythm}[exercisepoints=5,fig=$\spadesuit$]{Example $a=b$}
 \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u\cos\psi -v\sin\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\sin\psi + v\cos\psi
        \end{align}
        For small angles the following approximation can be used:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}
\end{mythm}

\vspace{0.1cm}

Here is problematic example:
\begin{mythm}[exercisepoints=10,]{Example Problematic}
 \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u\cos\psi -v\sin\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\sin\psi + v\cos\psi
        \end{align}
        For small angles the following approximation can be used:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}
\end{mythm}

\begin{mythm}[exercisepoints=5,fig=$\spadesuit$]{Example $a=b$}
 \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u\cos\psi -v\sin\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\sin\psi + v\cos\psi
        \end{align}
        For small angles the following approximation can be used:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}
\end{mythm}
\end{document}
```

i think passing 'MyTheoremEnv1' as Key instead of having just hardwired text Exercise might solve this?

Comment: I will be great feature to have native mdframed listof command, since this environmet can have a title and counter. p.s. I i put naive theorem in mdframed its title and number are printed. How can I supress this printings? I actually depends on theorem class i use right? and i need to redefine output in makeat/makeatother

Comment: sorry for misspelling

Comment: A listof something depends on single environments like theorem. `mdframed` is just a shell for such environments. If you want to have a new listof you have to declare it.

Comment: So it will be just command which accepts my declared mdframed variables? like this '\newlistof[section]{exercise}{idf}{\listexercise}'? + another commands

Comment: So just after environmet 
\addcontentsline{idf}{exercise_ounter}{Some Name.} and '\listofexercise' will work?

Comment: @LevanShoshiashvili there's no need to manually use `\addcontentsline`; this can be done automatically; please see my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{exercise}

\newtheorem{myexercise}{Exercise}[section]
\tikzset{myshadow/.style={                             % custom shadow with tikz
         opacity=.85,
         shadow xshift=0.15,
         shadow yshift=-0.15,
         shade,
         shading=axis,
         shading angle=230}
         } 
\tikzstyle{titregris} =
[draw=gray, line width=1.0pt,% 
        text=white, rectangle,  
        right,minimum height=.7cm,
       double,
       shade,
              top color=blue!40,
              bottom color=blue!5,
              rounded corners=8pt,
               opacity=1,
                                     shadow xshift=0.15,
                                     shadow yshift=-0.15,
                                     shade,
                                     shading=axis,
                                     shading angle=30,
              drop shadow,
        ]
\tikzstyle{pointstyle} =
[draw=red, thick, fill=red,% 
        text=white, rectangle,  
        right,minimum height=.7cm,
       double,
       shade,
              top color=red,
              bottom color=blue!5,
              rounded corners=3pt,
              drop shadow
        ]        

%\renewcommand*\theexercise{Exercise \textnumero\arabic{exercise}}
\makeatletter
\def\mdf@@exercisepoints{}%new mdframed key:
\define@key{mdf}{exercisepoints}{%
\def\mdf@@exercisepoints{#1}
}
\def\mdf@@fig{}%new mdframed key:
\define@key{mdf}{fig}{%
\def\mdf@@fig{#1}
}
\def\mdf@@title{}%new mdframed key:
\define@key{mdf}{title}{%
\def\mdf@@title{#1}
}


\mdfdefinestyle{exercisestyle}{%
middlelinewidth=1.2pt,roundcorner=5pt,linecolor=gray,
 apptotikzsetting={\tikzset{mdfbackground/.append style={top color=blue!40, bottom color=white}}},
innertopmargin=1.2\baselineskip,
skipabove={\dimexpr0.5\baselineskip+\topskip\relax},
skipbelow={-1em},
 shadow=true,
 shadowcolor=blue!35,
needspace=3\baselineskip,
frametitlefont=\sffamily\bfseries,
singleextra={%
\node[titregris,xshift=1cm] at (P-|O) %
{~\mdf@frametitlefont{Exercise~\textnumero\theexercise}~\mdf@@title};
\ifdefempty{\mdf@@exercisepoints}%
{}
{\node[pointstyle,left,xshift=-1cm] at (P)%
{~\mdf@frametitlefont{\mdf@@exercisepoints pt.}~};},%
\ifdefempty{\mdf@@fig}%
{}%
{\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in node[fill=blue!40,circle,inner sep=1pt,font=\color{white}] at (P|-0,0.5*\y2+0.5*\y1)  {\mdf@@fig};}% 
},
firstextra={%
\node[titregris,xshift=1cm] at (P-|O) %
{~\mdf@frametitlefont{Exercise~\textnumero\theexercise}~~\mdf@@title};
\ifdefempty{\mdf@@exercisepoints }%
{}%
{\node[pointstyle,left,xshift=-1cm] at (P)%
{~\mdf@frametitlefont{\mdf@@exercisepoints points}~};},%
},
}
\newcommand\listmdfname{List of Exercises}
\newcommand\listofmdframed{\section*{\listmdfname}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
              {\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
\@starttoc{mdf}}
\newenvironment{mythm}[2][]
  {\refstepcounter{exercise}\addcontentsline{mdf}{figure}{Exercise~\theexercise~#2}\begin{mdframed}[style=exercisestyle,#1,title=#2]}
  {\end{mdframed}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listofmdframed

\begin{mythm}[exercisepoints=10,fig=$\spadesuit$]{Example $E=mc^2$}
 \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u\cos\psi -v\sin\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\sin\psi + v\cos\psi
        \end{align}
        For small angles the following approximation can be used:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}
\end{mythm}

\begin{mythm}[exercisepoints=5,fig=$\spadesuit$]{Example $a=b$}
 \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u\cos\psi -v\sin\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\sin\psi + v\cos\psi
        \end{align}
        For small angles the following approximation can be used:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}
\end{mythm}

\vspace{0.1cm}

Here is problematic example:
\begin{mythm}[exercisepoints=10,fig=$\spadesuit$]{Example Problematic}
 \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u\cos\psi -v\sin\psi\displaybreak\\
            \dot{e} &= u\sin\psi + v\cos\psi
        \end{align}
        For small angles the following approximation can be used:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}
\end{mythm}

\begin{mythm}[exercisepoints=5,fig=$\spadesuit$]{Example $a=b$}
 \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u\cos\psi -v\sin\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\sin\psi + v\cos\psi
        \end{align}
        For small angles the following approximation can be used:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}
\end{mythm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I used the LaTeX kernel's `@starttoc` to create a new list that will behave in a fashion completely analogous to the LoF, Lot; the file extension used is `mdf` (information for this new list will be written to the fil `<name>.mdf`); the name used for this list can be controlled using `\listmdfname`.

The `mythm` environment has one optional argument, to pass options to the optional argument of `mdframed`, and a mandatory argument that will be used as an entry in the new list and to give a title to the `mdframed` environment.

#### Some additional comments:

1. Your code had

   ```
   \renewcommand*\theexercise{Exercise \textnumero\arabic{exercise}}
   ```

and this is not the best choice, `\theexercise` is meant to hold the representation for a counter, and adding `Exercise \textnumero` might produce undesired results (in cross-references, for example). I changed this in my code. The extra string is added outside the counter representation.

2. Also, I stepped the counter in the `mythm` environment (avoiding the unnecessary counter gymnastics mentioned in a comment).
3. If you want the counter to reset in a given sectional unit, the quickest way is to use (for example, for chapters)

   ```
   \usepackage{chngcntr}
   \counterwithin{exercise}{chapter}
   ```

(the line `\counterwithin` must appear after the definition of the counter).

#### Update:

If I understand the new requirement made in a comment, one can use the same settings for `mdframed` for various environments with a variable title; the idea would be to have a macro for the title and let each environment redefine the title macro appropriately (I called `\mymdftitle` this macro in the following example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{exercise}
\newcommand\mymdftitle{}

\tikzset{myshadow/.style={                             % custom shadow with tikz
         opacity=.85,
         shadow xshift=0.15,
         shadow yshift=-0.15,
         shade,
         shading=axis,
         shading angle=230}
         } 
\tikzstyle{titregris} =
[draw=gray, line width=1.0pt,% 
        text=white, rectangle,  
        right,minimum height=.7cm,
       double,
       shade,
              top color=blue!40,
              bottom color=blue!5,
              rounded corners=8pt,
               opacity=1,
                                     shadow xshift=0.15,
                                     shadow yshift=-0.15,
                                     shade,
                                     shading=axis,
                                     shading angle=30,
              drop shadow,
        ]
\tikzstyle{pointstyle} =
[draw=red, thick, fill=red,% 
        text=white, rectangle,  
        right,minimum height=.7cm,
       double,
       shade,
              top color=red,
              bottom color=blue!5,
              rounded corners=3pt,
              drop shadow
        ]        

%\renewcommand*\theexercise{Exercise \textnumero\arabic{exercise}}
\makeatletter
\def\mdf@@exercisepoints{}%new mdframed key:
\define@key{mdf}{exercisepoints}{%
\def\mdf@@exercisepoints{#1}
}
\def\mdf@@fig{}%new mdframed key:
\define@key{mdf}{fig}{%
\def\mdf@@fig{#1}
}
\def\mdf@@title{}%new mdframed key:
\define@key{mdf}{title}{%
\def\mdf@@title{#1}
}

\mdfdefinestyle{exercisestyle}{%
  middlelinewidth=1.2pt,
  roundcorner=5pt,
  linecolor=gray,
 apptotikzsetting={\tikzset{mdfbackground/.append style={
  top color=blue!40, bottom color=white}}},
  innertopmargin=1.2\baselineskip,
  skipabove={\dimexpr0.5\baselineskip+\topskip\relax},
  skipbelow={-1em},
  shadow=true,
  shadowcolor=blue!35,
  needspace=3\baselineskip,
  frametitlefont=\sffamily\bfseries,
  singleextra={%
    \node[titregris,xshift=1cm] at (P-|O) %
    {\mdf@frametitlefont{\mymdftitle}\mdf@@title~};
    \ifdefempty{\mdf@@exercisepoints}%
      {}
      {\node[pointstyle,left,xshift=-1cm] at (P)%
      {~\mdf@frametitlefont{\mdf@@exercisepoints pt.}~};},%
    \ifdefempty{\mdf@@fig}%
      {}%
      {\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in node[fill=blue!40,circle,inner   sep=1pt,font=\color{white}] at (P|-0,0.5*\y2+0.5*\y1)  {\mdf@@fig};}},
  firstextra={%
    \node[titregris,xshift=1cm] at (P-|O) %
    {~\mdf@frametitlefont{\mymdftitle}~~\mdf@@title};
    \ifdefempty{\mdf@@exercisepoints }%
      {}%
      {\node[pointstyle,left,xshift=-1cm] at (P)%
      {~\mdf@frametitlefont{\mdf@@exercisepoints points}~};},%
  },
}

\newcommand\listmdfname{List of Exercises}

\newcommand\listofmdframed{%
  \section*{\listmdfname}%
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listmdfname}{\MakeUppercase\listmdfname}%
  \@starttoc{mdf}}

\newenvironment{mythm}[2][]
  {\renewcommand\mymdftitle{~Exercise~\textnumero\theexercise~}%
    \refstepcounter{exercise}%
    \addcontentsline{mdf}{figure}{Exercise~\theexercise~#2}
    \begin{mdframed}[style=exercisestyle,#1,title=#2]%
  }
  {\end{mdframed}}

\newenvironment{myanother}[2][]
  {\renewcommand\mymdftitle{~A new title~}%
    \begin{mdframed}[style=exercisestyle,#1,title=#2]%
  }
  {\end{mdframed}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listofmdframed

\begin{mythm}[exercisepoints=10,fig=$\spadesuit$]{Example $E=mc^2$}
 \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u\cos\psi -v\sin\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\sin\psi + v\cos\psi
        \end{align}
        For small angles the following approximation can be used:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}
\end{mythm}

\begin{myanother}{Additional Information}
 \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u\cos\psi -v\sin\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\sin\psi + v\cos\psi
        \end{align}
        For small angles the following approximation can be used:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}
\end{myanother}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: excellent..tanks..I dont know too much latex programming internals . I used example from link above and wrapped mdframed env with command + tocloft..but your approach is much better

Comment: this transformation formulaes getting popular :) ..just kidding :) p.s. and of course i just need renewcommand for chapter/section/ numbering during sectioning i guess

Comment: I added counter to code ' {\addcontentsline{mdf}{figure}{\theexercise~ #2}' and counters go strange in listof..The first counter starts from 0..if i step counter on the top, tnan environmet conter is +1 extra

Comment: fixed it with this one: \newenvironment{mythm}[2][]
  {\addtocounter{exercise}{+1} \addcontentsline{mdf}{figure}{\theexercise #2}\addtocounter{exercise}{-1} \begin{mdframed}[style=exercisestyle,#1,title=#2]}
     {\end{mdframed}} before entering in environmet counter is not increased yet and this -1 data is written to toc

Comment: and better is \theexercise{} just for extra space

Comment: @LevanShoshiashvili all those manipulations with the counter are not necessary; please see my updated answer, and specially the final remarks.

Comment: hmm strange behavior..it was not before...place 3,4 of  `mythm` blocks (just copy/paste) and you will se very strange behavior of 3rd object when it is splited across pages.

Comment: @LevanShoshiashvili if you are referring to the clubsuit decoration when the frame splits, that part of your original code: you have `{\node[pointstyle, left,xshift=1cm]  {$\clubsuit$};}` inside `firstextra`. If you don't want that, then don't use it. To prevent a page break in some undesired location, you can use the option `nobreak=true`.

Comment: Ok..but during page brake clubsuit is changed :) and title also gets lost in initial code i stared with clubsuit was just disappearing and other decorations were kept..its ok this behavior can be avoided..this is just user code not a class/style package..thanks again

Comment: changed 'fig=suit' to `bydefault fig is empty` works fine.So i can don't pass `fig` if frame splits

Comment: but in this last code title also gets lost..even i remove default suit thing

Comment: @LevanShoshiashvili it's impossible to know what you're talking about without seeing the actual code you are using. Please edit your question and add, as an edit, the code you are currently using and some text illustrating the problem. (Please don't overwrite the already existing code)

Comment: updated..I did not know if this was allowed. I got warning once , when i reposted question as answer to my own question :)

Comment: @LevanShoshiashvili Of course, it's allowed, but without deleting the previous code; otherwise the initial question and answer makes no sense! Please reedit, to include the old code and add the new code afterwards, with the new requirements.

Comment: Updated...with original code

Comment: found solution. I changed first extra like this in your code and I dont know how good is this change , but it works fine: `firstextra={%
\node[titregris,xshift=1cm] at (P-|O) %
{~\mdf@frametitlefont{მაგალითი~\textnumero\theexercise}~\mdf@@title};
\ifdefempty{\mdf@@exercisepoints }%
{}%
{\node[pointstyle,left,xshift=-1cm] at (P)%
{~\mdf@frametitlefont{\mdf@@exercisepoints points}~};},%
%{\node[pointstyle, left,xshift=1cm]  {$\clubsuit$};}
}`

Comment: @LevanShoshiashvili I just wrote that in my updated answer :-) Also, notice the use of `\displaybreak` in the third frame; long equations at the end of a page are problematic, so `\displaybreak` is needed.

Comment: @LevanShoshiashvili And sorry to insist on this, but please consider accepting answers to your questions.

Comment: now one more comes...for not dublicating code for different environmets 'MyExample1' and `MySolutionAnother` can envoronment name be passed to mdframe somehow? and i dont like global counter can it be created behind user?

Comment: @LevanShoshiashvili I don't fully understand your questions. Do you need another environment with similar settings but with a different name? Can we continue this discussion in chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9272/discussion-between-gonzalo-medina-and-levan-shoshiashvili)

Comment: @LevanShoshiashvili I've updated my answer (See the section under "Update") showing how to reuse the same settings without code duplication. I hope this is close to waht you need. Also, I noticed you discovered how to accept answers. Thank you! :-)